# Deserializing JSON to abstract class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string to a concrete class, which inherits from an abstract class, but I just can't get it working. I have googled and tried some solutions but they don't seem to work either.

This is what I have now:

```
abstract class AbstractClass { }

class ConcreteClass { }

public AbstractClass Decode(string jsonString)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    jss.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
    return (AbstractClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, null, jss);
}
```

However, if I try to cast the resulting object, it just doesn't work.

The reason why I don't use DeserializeObject is that I have **many concrete classes**.

Any suggestions?

- I am using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: for deserialization you need create object instance, but you can't create instance of abstract class

Comment: I want it to create an instance of a concrete class, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)

Comment: Best answer deserializing without type information : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30579193/1214248  using newtonsoft.json

Answer (score 98, accepted):

One may not want to use TypeNameHandling (because one wants more compact json or wants to use a specific name for the type variable other than "$type"). Meanwhile, the [customCreationConverter approach](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) will not work if one wants to deserialize the base class into any of multiple derived classes without knowing which one to use in advance.

An alternative is to use an int or other type in the base class and define a JsonConverter.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(BaseConverter))]
abstract class Base
{
    public int ObjType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class DerivedType1 : Base
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

class DerivedType2 : Base
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The JsonConverter for the base class can then deserialize the object based on its type. The complication is that to avoid a stack overflow (where the JsonConverter repeatedly calls itself), a custom contract resolver must be used during this deserialization.

```
public class BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && !objectType.IsAbstract)
            return null; // pretend TableSortRuleConvert is not specified (thus avoiding a stack overflow)
        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}

public class BaseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    static JsonSerializerSettings SpecifiedSubclassConversion = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new BaseSpecifiedConcreteClassConverter() };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Base));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        switch (jo["ObjType"].Value<int>())
        {
            case 1:
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedType1>(jo.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion);
            case 2:
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedType2>(jo.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion);
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // won't be called because CanWrite returns false
    }
}
```

That's it. Now you can use serialize/deserialize any derived class. You can also use the base class in other classes and serialize/deserialize those without any additional work:

```
class Holder
    {
        public List<Base> Objects { get; set; }
    }
string json = @"
        [
            {
                ""Objects"" : 
                [
                    { ""ObjType"": 1, ""Id"" : 1, ""Foo"" : ""One"" },
                    { ""ObjType"": 1, ""Id"" : 2, ""Foo"" : ""Two"" },
                ]
            },
            {
                ""Objects"" : 
                [
                    { ""ObjType"": 2, ""Id"" : 3, ""Bar"" : ""Three"" },
                    { ""ObjType"": 2, ""Id"" : 4, ""Bar"" : ""Four"" },
                ]
            },
        ]";

            List<Holder> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Holder>>(json);
            string serializedAgain = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            Debug.WriteLine(serializedAgain);
```

Comment: This is a great solution; the only improvement I would suggest is that instead of calling `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedType2>(jo.ToString(), SpecifiedSubclassConversion);`, you use the passed in serializer `Return jo.ToObject(t, serializer);`

Comment: then you'll get the stackoverflow exception

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful! Thank you very much for the code!

Comment: This is very helpfull. Can this also be used for nested json? Like in this example if the objects with ObjType 2 also have arrays with different objects.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. What about using `SpecifiedConcreteClassConverter<T>` for more generic usage?

Comment: If anyone else is wondering how to use this a different way: `JsonConverter[] converters = { new BaseConverter()};
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Base>>(result, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Converters = converters });` see: https://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/03/30/json-dotnet-deserialize-to-abstract-class-or-interface/

Comment: This does not work very well if a custom JSON serializer is used, and using the passed serializer instead will cause a recursive call that will fail. Anyone considering this solution may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947235/2279059 as well, which is similar, but doesn't have this issue, and is more simple, too.

Comment: This is great, however doing this will easily mess up the intellisense for future programmers, as it adds all this additional classes to the system. I wish there was a way to somehow hide them...

Answer (score 27):

I would suggest to use CustomCreationConverter in the following way:

```
public enum ClassDiscriminatorEnum
    {
        ChildClass1,
        ChildClass2
    }

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public abstract ClassDiscriminatorEnum Type { get; }
    }

    public class Child1 : BaseClass
    {
        public override ClassDiscriminatorEnum Type => ClassDiscriminatorEnum.ChildClass1;
        public int ExtraProperty1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child2 : BaseClass
    {
        public override ClassDiscriminatorEnum Type => ClassDiscriminatorEnum.ChildClass2;
    }

    public class BaseClassConverter : CustomCreationConverter<BaseClass>
    {
        private ClassDiscriminatorEnum _currentObjectType;

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var jobj = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);
            _currentObjectType = jobj["Type"].ToObject<ClassDiscriminatorEnum>();
            return base.ReadJson(jobj.CreateReader(), objectType, existingValue, serializer);
        }

        public override BaseClass Create(Type objectType)
        {
            switch (_currentObjectType)
            {
                case ClassDiscriminatorEnum.ChildClass1:
                    return new Child1();
                case ClassDiscriminatorEnum.ChildClass2:
                    return new Child2();
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the question, thank you very much!

Comment: This even works if a custom JSON serializer is used. The custom serializer is used to deserialize the derived object.

Comment: it didnt work for me when using baseclass as a property in the api controller - it wont deserialize? am i missing something?

Comment: I also think this is the cleanest solution, but it's not thread safe. _currentObjectType can potentially be overwritten from other threads. I've made it thread safe by determining the concrete type in ReadJson and passing that type to base.ReadJson. The Create method then receives these concrete types and can create instances of them with: (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType).

Answer (score 24):

Actually, as it has been stated in an update, the simplest way (in 2019) is to use a simple custom pre-defined JsonSerializerSettings, as explained [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)

```
        string jsonTypeNameAll = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(priceModels, Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
```

And for deserializing :

```
TDSPriceModels models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TDSPriceModels>(File.ReadAllText(jsonPath), new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
```

Comment: Note that if you could also use `TypeNameHandling.Auto` instead.
This setting will let JsonConvert decide when it needs to handle the `$type` when it really needs it. That can save a lot of space from the final file.

Comment: Please mind [CA2326: Do not use TypeNameHandling values other than None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2326)

Answer (score 23):

try something like this

```
public AbstractClass Decode(string jsonString)
{
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jss.Deserialize<ConcreteClass>(jsonString);
}
```

**UPDATE**
for this scenario methinks all work as you want

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract int GetInt();
}
public class Der:Base
{
    int g = 5;
    public override int GetInt()
    {
        return g+2;
    }
}
public class Der2 : Base
{
    int i = 10;
    public override int GetInt()
    {
        return i+17;
    }
}

....

var jset = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
Base b = new Der()
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b, jset);
....

Base c = (Base)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, jset);
```

where `c` type is `test.Base {test.Der}`

**UPDATE**

[@Gusman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class/20997869?noredirect=1#comment78675679_20997869) suggest use `TypeNameHandling.Objects` instead of `TypeNameHandling.All`. It is enough and it will produce a less verbose serialization.

Comment: The problem is that I have many concrete classes, so I don't know which one of them to use

Comment: @aochagavia so make your abstract class not abstract and use it:-)

Comment: It has abstract methods, that is why it is abstract... I will just put more information on the JSON, like classType or something like that.

Comment: can you provide sample how you try use this now?

Comment: @aochagavia and how you serialize your objects

Comment: I know this is old, but instead of `TypeNameHandling.All` using `TypeNameHandling.Objects` is enough and it will produce a less verbose serialization.

Comment: @Gusman, do you think we should add this suggestion to answer?

Comment: @Grundy Indeed I would add it, as json is extensively used for data transport through network is always better to keep as optimized as possible the output.

Answer (score 4):

```
 public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeString = jObject.Value<string>("Kind"); //Kind is a property in json , from which we know type of child classes
        var requiredType = RecoverType(typeString);

        return Serializer.Deserialize(jObject.CreateReader(), requiredType);
    }

    private Type RecoverType(string typeString)
    {
        if (typeString.Equals(type of child class1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return typeof(childclass1);
        if (typeString.Equals(type of child class2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return typeof(childclass2);            

        throw new ArgumentException("Unrecognized type");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Base class).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || typeof((Base class) == objectType;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
}
```

**Now add this converter in JsonSerializerSettings as below**

```
   var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
        jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());
```

**After adding serialize or deserialize base class object as below**

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>("json string", jsonSerializerSettings );
```

Comment: Why the static `JsonSerializer` instance rather than using the one that was passed into ReadJson

Comment: I've combined this with the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036138/how-to-ignore-base-class-jsonconverter-when-deserializing-derived-classes - works a trick. No need for the static JsonSerializer.

Comment: The `jsonSerializerSettings` should also be added in the `ReadJson` function, otherwise recursions won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it with another way, maybe this would help someone:
I have json that contains in it several fields that are always the same, except for one field called "data" that can be a different type of class every time.
I would like to de-serialize it without analayzing every filed specific.
My solution is:
To define the main class (with 'Data' field) with , the field Data is type T.
Whenever that I de-serialize, I specify the type:

**MainClass:**

```
public class MainClass<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public Statuses Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public static MainClass<T> Parse(string mainClsTxt)
    {
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass<T>>(mainClsTxt);
        return response;

    }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

**Product**

```
public class Product
{

    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock")]
    public int Stock { get; set; }

}
```

**Using**

```
var v = MainClass<User>.Parse(userJson);
var v2 = MainClass<Product>.Parse(productJson);
```

**json example**

```
userJson: "{"status":1,"description":"my description","data":{"id":12161347,"first_name":"my fname","last_name":"my lname"}}"

productJson: "{"status":1,"description":"my description","data":{"product_id":5,"product_name":"my product","stock":1000}}"
```

Comment: What I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,Type objectType,
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            var target = Create(objectType, jObject);
            serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);
            return target;
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now implement this interface

```
public class SportActivityConverter : JsonCreationConverter<BaseSportActivity>
{
    protected override BaseSportActivity Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        BaseSportActivity result = null;
        try
        {
            switch ((ESportActivityType)jObject["activityType"].Value<int>())
            {
                case ESportActivityType.Football:
                    result = jObject.ToObject<FootballActivity>();
                    break;

                case ESportActivityType.Basketball:
                    result = jObject.ToObject<BasketballActivity>();
                    break;
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return result;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Only works if you decorate your baseclass with: `[JsonConverter(typeof(BaseConverter))]` and add the `CanWrite` function with `return false` to the class `SportActivityConverter`.