# newtonsoft json deserialize with subclassed collection

Tags: json, inheritance, serialization, collections, json.net

I have a series of classes `MyConcreteClass : MyBaseClass` and a series of collection classes `MyConcreteCollection : MyBaseCollection`.

Where the fun part is that

```
public abstract class MyBaseCollection
{
    public List<MyBaseClass> MyItems :get; set;}
}
```

It serializes fine, and the objects inside MyItems do show up as the right items (lookin in the JSON with `{ TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };` set

My problem is when I go to deserialize - obviously we can't create an object of `List<MyBaseClass>` (It is abstract) - I need to deserialize to `List<MyConcreteClass>`
The good news?  The `List<MyConcreteClass>` is ALWAYS the same for each type of `MyConcreteCollection`, aka

`MyFirstCollectionType: MyBaseCollection` the MyItems will always be of type `FistConcreteType : MyBaseClass` and  `MySecondCollectionType: MyBaseCollection` will always be of type `SecondConcreteType : MyBaseClass`

I *THINK* it might be just a custom Converter, but I just don't get it.

Comment: Is there any chance you could [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class