# System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I want to know the equivalent of the `ToObject<>()` method in [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) for *System.Text.Json*.

Using Json.NET you can use any `JToken` and convert it to a class. For example:

```cs
var str = ""; // Some JSON string
var jObj = JObject.Parse(str);
var myClass = jObj["SomeProperty"].ToObject<SomeClass>();
```

How would we be able to do this with .NET Core 3's new `System.Text.Json`?

```cs
var str = ""; // Some JSON string
var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(str);
var myClass = jDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("SomeProperty"). <-- now what??
```

Initially, I was thinking I'd just convert the `JsonElement` that is returned in `jDoc.RootElement.GetPRoperty("SomeProperty")` to a string and then deserialize that string. But I feel that might not be the most efficient method, and I can't really find documentation on doing it another way.

Answer (score 127):

**In .NET 6**, extension methods were added to [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer#methods) to deserialize an object directly from a [`JsonElement`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.Element.cs) or [`JsonDocument`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.Document.cs):

```
public static partial class JsonSerializer
{
    public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonDocument document, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static object? Deserialize(this JsonDocument document, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonDocument document, JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo);
    public static object? Deserialize(this JsonDocument document, Type returnType, JsonSerializerContext context);

    public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static object? Deserialize(this JsonElement element, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonElement element, JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo);
    public static object? Deserialize(this JsonElement element, Type returnType, JsonSerializerContext context);
}
```

Now you will be able to do:

```
using var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(str);
var myClass = jDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("SomeProperty").Deserialize<SomeClass>();
```

Notes:

- `JsonDocument` is disposable.  According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument#remarks), *This class utilizes resources from pooled memory... failure to properly dispose this object will result in the memory not being returned to the pool, which will increase [GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) impact across various parts of the framework.*

  So, be sure to declare your `jDoc` with a `using` statement.
- The new methods should be present in [.NET 6.0 Preview RC1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/preview/api-diff/rc1/.Net/6.0.0-rc1_System.Text.Json.md).

  They were added in response to the enhancement request *[We should be able serialize and serialize from DOM #31274](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274)*, which has been closed.
- Similar [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1%28system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions%29) were added for the new [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode) mutable JSON document node as well

  ```
  public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonNode? node, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null)
  public static object? Deserialize(this JsonNode? node, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null)
  public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonNode? node, JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo)
  public static object? Deserialize(this JsonNode? node, Type returnType, JsonSerializerContext context)
  ```

---

**In .NET 5 and earlier** these methods do not exist.  As a workaround, you may get better performance by writing to an intermediate `byte` buffer rather than to a string, since both `JsonDocument` and `Utf8JsonReader` work directly with `byte` spans rather than strings or `char` spans.  As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to#serialize-to-utf-8):

> Serializing to UTF-8 is about 5-10% faster than using the string-based methods. The difference is because the bytes (as UTF-8) don't need to be converted to strings (UTF-16).

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        var bufferWriter = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter))
            element.WriteTo(writer);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bufferWriter.WrittenSpan, options);
    }

    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonDocument document, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        if (document == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(document));
        return document.RootElement.ToObject<T>(options);
    }
}
```

A demo fiddle is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uRwlVv).

Comment: Is it safe to `Deserialize()` using `options` if these options are not used when writing the internal buffer?

Comment: Still using this answer on dotnet 5 some 18 months later. Needs a ```writer.Flush();``` after ```element.WriteTo(writer);``` though otherwise you sometimes get ```System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'Expected depth to be zero at the end of the JSON payload. There is an open JSON object or array that should be closed.```

Comment: @mclayton - I do dispose of the `Utf8JsonWriter writer` via a `using` statement, and according to the docs the [dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.dispose) *In the case of IBufferWriter, this advances the underlying `IBufferWriter<T>` based on what has been written so far.* and the [flush method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.flush) also *advances the underlying `IBufferWriter<T>` based on what has been written so far.*  Doing both does not seem necessary.

Comment: @mclayton - Thus it is surprising that `writer.Flush()` is required as well as the `using` statement.   can you share a [mcve] showing a case where `Flush()` and `Dispose()` are both required?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was “using” the C# 8.0 form of using ... ```using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter);``` so the ```Dispose``` only gets called at the end of the function, which totally changes the behaviour of the code and needed the ```Flush``` to fix it. What a difference a couple of brackets makes!

Comment: If the  `JsonElement` holds a smaller json string (length wise), will it still be better to do like you suggest, or could the cost of setting up the writers be less performant compared to using `GetRawText()`? ... Or set the Deserialize method up such writer itself, if it gets a `string`?

Comment: @Ason - you can check the source.  Internally the contents of `JsonElement` are stored as a `ReadOnlyMemory<byte> segment` utf8 byte sequence, so [`GetRawText()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.6/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.cs#L1165) => [`GetRawValueAsString(int index)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.6/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonDocument.cs#L756) transcodes that to a new string before returning it.

Comment: @Ason - And `JsonSerializer` internally deserializes from utf8 byte sequences, so [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(string json, ...)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.6/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.String.cs#L86) transcodes back to utf8 before deserializing.  My methods simply skip the transcoding back and forth.

Comment: Thanks...were hoping for that :)

Comment: `ArrayBufferWriter` seems to be a .NET Core thing. Can I replace it with `ArrayPoolBufferWriter` from `Microsoft.Toolkit.HighPerformance` nuget package when working in .NET Framework 4.8?

Comment: @dotNET - Sure.  You can use anything that implements `IBufferWriter<Byte>`.  It seems to work fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/SdwAUt, and it might result in better performance if you do so.  Be sure to dispose it afterwards e.g. `using var bufferWriter = new ArrayPoolBufferWriter<byte>();`.

Answer (score 110):

I came across the same issue, so I wrote some extension methods, which work fine for now.  It would be nice if they provided this as built-in method to avoid the additional allocation to a string.

```cs
public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element)
{
    var json = element.GetRawText();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonDocument document)
{
    var json = document.RootElement.GetRawText();
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
}
```

Then use as follows:

```cs
jDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("SomeProperty").ToObject<SomeClass>();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing as well. I posted the question to see if there was a more efficient way without that string allocation as you have mentioned. Maybe we'll have to wait until system.text.json is a little more mature.

Comment: Yup, though it isn't about string allocation only. It's more about parsing the textual representation of the whole JSON again. It was already parsed once when the JsonElement/Document was created so it's a waste of CPU too.

Comment: dude... EXACTLY WHAT I Was trying to do. Thanks so much for adding this!

Answer (score 11):

Same as [dbc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063/271992), just including the methods which allow you to specify a return type via `Type returnType`.

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        var bufferWriter = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter))
        {
            element.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bufferWriter.WrittenSpan, options);
    }

    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonDocument document, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(document));
        }

        return document.RootElement.ToObject<T>(options);
    }       

    public static object ToObject(this JsonElement element, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        var bufferWriter = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter))
        {
            element.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(bufferWriter.WrittenSpan, returnType, options);
    }

    public static object ToObject(this JsonDocument document, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(document));
        }

        return document.RootElement.ToObject(returnType, options);
    }       
}
```

Comment: serializing back to a text seems not a efficient way

Answer (score 10):

**.NET 6** introduced the **[System.Text.Json.Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes?view=net-6.0)** namespace, which provides a way to do this using almost exactly the same syntax as Json.Net:

```
var str = ""; // some json string
var node = JsonNode.Parse(str);
var myClass = node["SomeProperty"].Deserialize<SomeClass>();
```

---

The namespace includes 4 new types: `JsonNode`, `JsonArray`, `JsonObject`, and `JsonValue` which can be used to access or modify values within the DOM. [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) is the base class for the other three types.

The `Deserialize` extension methods listed in [dbc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063/9665021) have also been added to operate on `JsonNode`, eg:

```
public static TValue? Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonNode? node, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
```

`JsonNode` is not disposable so you do not need to use the `using` syntax.

Use `AsObject()` or `AsArray()` to parse to a [`JsonObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonobject?view=net-6.0) or [`JsonArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonarray?view=net-6.0), respectively:

```
// parse array
JsonArray arr = JsonNode.Parse(@"[{""Name"": ""Bob"", ""Age"":30}]").AsArray();
// parse object
JsonObject obj = JsonNode.Parse(@"{""Name"": ""Bob"", ""Age"":30}").AsObject();
// get a value
var date = JsonNode.Parse(@"{""Date"":""2021-12-21T13:24:46+04:00""}")["Date"].GetValue<DateTimeOffset>();
```

Once the json has been parsed it's possible to navigate, filter and transform the DOM and/or apply `Deserialize<T>()` to map to your concrete type.

To serialize back to a json string you can use `ToJsonString()`, eg:

```
string innerNodeJson = node["SomeProperty"].ToJsonString();
```

Please see this answer to [Equivalent of JObject in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71018559/9665021) for more details information about `JsonObject`.

Comment: This seems to suffer from issues in that if you try and deserialize this to a `Dictionary<string, object>` every value in the dictionary is still a `JsonElement` as opposed to a `JsonNode` making is extremely difficult to work with.