# JsonElement equivalent to JObject.ToObject

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I'm porting a core 2.2 SDK to 3.0. Newtonsoft has been replaced by a native Json engine. My SDK takes a JObject and converts it to a concrete type using `ToObject<T>()`

Whats the equivalent of this with a JsonElement?

I want to deserialize a `Message` class whose `Event` property can only be determined at runtime  :

```
private class Message
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public JsonElement Event { get; set; }
    public string[] GenericArguments { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

In System.Text.Json I have to use this code to serialize the `Event` to JSON and then deserialize it again to the final type :

```
    private dynamic ParseTypeData(Message message)
    {
        Type type = typeFinder.GetEventType(message.Type);
        if (message.GenericArguments.Length > 0)
        {
            var genericArguments = message.GenericArguments
                .Select(typeFinder.GetType)
                .ToArray();

            type = type.MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
        }

        var json = message.Event.GetRawText();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, type, Options);
    }
```

In JSON.NET the class was :

```
    private class Message
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public JObject Event { get; set; }
        public string[] GenericArguments { get; set; }
        public int? Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And deserializing `Event` only needed :

```
return message.Event.ToObject(type);
```

Comment: You're asking how to deserialize a JSON element into an object. Why go through JsonElement? System.Text.Json is tailored focused on *very specific* scenarios around ASP.NET Core serialization. DOM parsing to JsonDocument, full deserialization using JsonSerializer or extremely-low-level not-quite-SAX with Utf8JsonReader. There's not even a *stream* JSon reader

Comment: I do not know the type until runtime, the dto looks like https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/8a63fb1d78c722e8c47b38a035746da1821ea3ac/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNetCore/EventAggregation/EventProxy.cs#L166 and I deserlize like https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/8a63fb1d78c722e8c47b38a035746da1821ea3ac/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNetCore/EventAggregation/EventProxy.cs#L90

Comment: This was much more elegant in newtonsoft https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/9c61efe49300823e56cf5949627a9460ffe6e7a0/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNetCore/EventAggregation/EventProxy.cs#L88

Comment: you should post the code in the question itself, so people understand the context - you're using SignalR and  have a message class whose payload can be any kind of object. What you as for is a utility method in  Json.NET too - the string is parsed into a JObject *first* and then `ToObject` constructs and fills a custom object using reflection. System.Text.Json isn't that kind of parser *yet* - it doesn't have such utility methods, it's focused on fast parsing in the pipeline. Its job is to give you a `Message` quickly with minimal allocations

Comment: Perhaps you can write your own custom converter? That would be an option in JSON.NET too, to return the payload directly rather than going through a JObject. In JSON.NET this will probably halve the number of allocations

Comment: Any tips on how to use it without reinveting the wheel? I did have a quick look but I do not want to parse the json myself.

Comment: Why not use NewtonSoft.Json? Nothing stops you using it. It is not dprecated, just not really a good fit for some common Aspnet.Core workflows and thus replaced in these instances. But for your usecase (flexible deserialization) it is plainly trumps the advantage of speed .

Comment: @ChristianSauer even in JSON.NET, using a custom converter will reduce CPU/RAM in half. That's the quick solution but the cost is already significant, especially for an event aggregator library.

Comment: @ChristianSauer, its for a library. Newtonsoft was standard part of Core 2.2, its been replaced by System.Text.Json. DO not want to include none standard parts in a lib.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cant really see how I can use the System.Text.Json converter without doing all the conversion from scratch.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182).