# What's the counterpart to JObject.FromObject in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

With Newtonsoft Json you can convert an object to a `JObject` by calling `JObject.FromObject(object)`.

Is there a counterpart in System.Text.Json to get a `JsonDocument` from an object?

Comment: There isn't one. [The documentation lists all of the members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1), and there are no methods which take an `object` parameter. You'll have to serialize the object.

Comment: Related: [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274) for it.

But now there is no such methods. You can try

```
 using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(object)))
 {
    ...
 }
```

One more [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29501)

Answer (score 6):

As of .NET 6.0 (comes with [System.Text.Json 6.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/6.0.0)), [`JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetodocument?view=net-6.0) is available.

```cs
JsonDocument doc = JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument(yourObject);
```