# Try to serialize the response in two different models

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am trying to handle response that is different from what I expect normally.
Normally I would expect a response that looks like the Item model below:

```
  public class Item
  {
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
  }
```

But if the DB is down or not responding, it returns this type of answer as seen from the DbError model below:

```
public class DbError
  {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Cause { get; set; }
  }
```

Typically I would try to serialize the response like this:

```
Item? response = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Item>(jsonString);
```

How can I try to serialize as an Item but in case that the db is returning the error, serialize with the DbError model?

Comment: Where do you get this jsonString from?  does it send any more information with the jsonString or its just the jsonString?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options. Assuming default `System.Text.Json` is used to handle json - either write custom converter similar to one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121568/2501279) (existence of a property should be used as discriminant not a property value as in that answer) or deserialize dynamically. For example using `JsonNode` API which became available since .NET 6 ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0)):

```cs
var doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonString))
if (doc.ContainsKey("response")) 
{
    var item = doc.Deserialize<Item>();
}
else
{
    var error = doc.Deserialize<DbError>();
}
```

For earlier versions:

```cs
using var doc = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(jsonString);
if (doc.RootElement.TryGetProperty("response", out var _))
{
    var item = doc.Deserialize<Item>();
}
else
{
    var error = doc.Deserialize<DbError>();
}
```

If you are using Newtonsoft's Json.NET both approaches can be implemented with it too.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need what is normally called "envelope". Don't return your item directly, but wrap it into another object. Something like this:

```
public class Envelope<T>
{
   public T Data {get;}
   public Error Error {get;}
   public bool IsSuccessful => (this.Error is null);
}
```

your API consumer would have to check if `IsSuccessful` is true and otherwise inspect the contents of the `Error` property.