# How to reset an Utf8JsonReader to its starting position?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

I know from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=net-6.0) that this is technically not possible (`Utf8JsonReader` is forward-only with no caching mechanism), but I want to know if I can achieve something equivalent in behaviour.

Below is my use case and the problem I have with `Utf8JsonReader`'s incapability of resetting to its start position.

---

I have some classes and subclasses that I want to (de-)serialize to JSON using `System.Text.Json`. Serialization works perfectly without any custom `JsonConverter` needed; I just need to add a `JsonStringEnumConverter`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(BarBase bar) { Bar = bar; }

    public BarBase Bar { get; init; }
}

public class BarBase
{
    public BarBase(string text, BarType type) { Text = text; Type = type; }

    public string Text { get; init; }
    public BarType Type { get; init; }
}

public class BarSub1 : BarBase
{
    public BarSub1(string text) : base(text, BarType.sub1) {}
}

public class BarSub2 : BarBase
{
    public BarSub2(string text) : base(text, BarType.sub2) {}
}

public enum BarType { base, sub1, sub2 }
```

Here is the serialization:

```
var foo = new Foo(new BarSub1("bar"));
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo,
    new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() } };
// json is { "Bar": { "Text": "bar", "Type": "sub1" } }
```

Deserialization does not work out of the box (it does not throw errors but it always deserializes my `Bar` objects to `BarBase`, which I don't want); for that I need a `JsonConverter` according to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60792311/5333340). So I tried writing one, but can't get it working. The problem is: In order to determine the type I want to deserialize, I need to read a bit of the Json (until I get the `Type` property). So the `Utf8JsonReader` is not at its starting position any more. But since the `Type` property is part of the class (and part of what the `JsonSerializer` handles), I cannot start deserializting with the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method after I have already ran over the `Type` property. I would need to call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` before any `Read()`ing was done.

```
public class BarConverter : JsonConverter<BarBase>
{
    public override BarBase Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Type BarTypeToType(BarType t)
        {
            switch (t)
            {
                case base: return typeof(BarBase);
                case sub1: return typeof(BarSub1);
                case sub2: return typeof(BarSub2);
                default: throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException("missing start object");

        bool discriminatorFound = false;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                continue;
            if (reader.GetString() != "Type")
                continue;
            discriminatorFound = true;
            break;
        }

        if (!discriminatorFound)
            throw new JsonException($"type discriminator property not found");

        if (!reader.Read() || reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.String)
            throw new JsonException("type discriminator value does not exist or is not a string");

        var typeString = reader.GetString();
        if (!Enum.TryParse(typeString, out BarType enumValue))
            throw new JsonException($"value {typeString} is not an element of {nameof(BarType)}");

        // PROBLEM: This doesn't work, since we are not at the start position any more!
        BarBase instance = (BarBase)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, BarTypeToType(enumValue), options)!;

        if (!reader.Read() || reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            throw new JsonException("missing end object");

        return instance;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BaseType value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352365/3744182) by [Somaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342856/somaar) to [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).  It takes advantage of the fact that `Utf8JsonWriter` is a **`struct`** to make a backup copy, then re-read starting from the backup copy.  Do note ***this only works within the context of `JsonConverter<T>.Read()`*** because the entire JSON stream is preloaded before the call; outside of `Read()` you need to deal with asynchrony.

Comment: The fact that copying the `Utf8JsonReader` works is confirmed by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json/66352365#comment115472745_59744873) by [ahsonkhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12509023/ahsonkhan) who was I believe one of the original MSFT developers.  But it only works because `JsonSerializer` preloads the entire JSON sequence before calling the converter, if MSFT ever changes that design copying the reader might stop working (while loading into `JsonDocument` is guaranteed to work).

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this?

Comment: @dbc No, you already gave an answer in your first comment.

Comment: @dbc Utf8JsonWriter is definitely not a struct like the reader.  I assume this was just a typo given the question, your comment, and your linked answer are all about deserialization, but I thought it best to clarify because Google is bringing in people (me) looking specifically for information about Utf8JsonWriter.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks, you're right, my comment should have said *It takes advantage of the fact that **`Utf8JsonReader`** is a `struct` to make a backup copy*.  But of course I can't edit my comment any longer, which is just another reason that I/we shouldn't be answering in comments.