# Convert object to System.Text.Json.JsonElement

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Let's say I have an object of type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to convert it to System.Text.Json.JsonElement. The only way I found is:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyClass { Data = "value" });

using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

var jsonElement = document.RootElement;
```

Seems strange that I have to serialize it first and then parse it. Is there a better approach for this?

Previously I was using `JObject` from Newtonsoft.Json and I could do it like this:

```
var jobject = JObject.FromObject(new MyClass { Data = "value" });
```

Comment: What are you planing to do with it next?

Comment: I'm writing web API and there's a controller method which receives a model containing `Type` (enum) and `Content` (JsonElement). Then I convert `Content` to a concrete class based on `Type` enum. The conversion from `object` to `JsonElement` is needed in unit testing.

Comment: Related: [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Saw that, but I need the opposite.

Comment: Right, it's not a dup, it's simply a confirmation that the desired API doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This is advice coming from experience, especially after checking the [comparison in features between newtonsoft and the system.text.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to). Stick with newtonsoft for the foreseeable future. You know it's going to be time to switch, when they decide to deprecate Newtonsoft. I know it doesn't answer your specific question, but I think it may be helpful in the long run

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**In .NET 6** methods are being added to `JsonSerializer` to serialize an object directly to a [`JsonElement`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Element.cs) or [`JsonDocument`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Document.cs):

```
public static partial class JsonSerializer
{
    public static JsonDocument SerializeToDocument<TValue>(TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static JsonDocument SerializeToDocument(object? value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static JsonDocument SerializeToDocument<TValue>(TValue value, JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo);
    public static JsonDocument SerializeToDocument(object? value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerContext context);

    public static JsonElement SerializeToElement<TValue>(TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static JsonElement SerializeToElement(object? value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions? options = null);
    public static JsonElement SerializeToElement<TValue>(TValue value, JsonTypeInfo<TValue> jsonTypeInfo);
    public static JsonElement SerializeToElement(object? value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerContext context);
}
```

Thus in .NET 6 you will be able to do:

```
using var jsonDocument = JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument(new MyClass { Data = "value" });
```

or

```
var jsonElement = JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(new MyClass { Data = "value" });
```

Notes:

- [`JsonSerializerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializercontext?view=net-6.0) and [`JsonTypeInfo<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo-1?view=net-6.0) are newly exposed in .NET 6 and provide metadata about a set of types, or a single type `T`, that is relevant to JSON serialization.  They are used when serializing using metadata and code generated at compile time. See [Try the new System.Text.Json source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/#introducing-jsontypeinfot-jsontypeinfo-and-jsonserializercontext) for details.
- `JsonDocument` is `IDisposable`, and in fact must needs be disposed because, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#jsondocument-is-idisposable):

  > `JsonDocument` builds an in-memory view of the data into a pooled buffer. Therefore, unlike `JObject` or `JArray` from Newtonsoft.Json, the `JsonDocument` type implements `IDisposable` and needs to be used inside a `using` block.

  In your sample code you do not dispose of the document returned by `JsonDocument.Parse()`, but you should.
- The new methods should be present in [.NET 6 RC1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/preview/api-diff/preview7/.Net/6.0.0-preview7_System.Text.Json.md).

**In .NET 5 and earlier** a method equivalent to `JObject.FromObject()` is not currently available out of the box in `System.Text.Json`.  There is an open enhancement about this, currently targeted for [Future](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/milestone/1):

- [We should be able serialize and serialize from DOM #31274](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274).

In the interim you may get better performance by serializing to an intermediate `byte` array rather than to a string, since both `JsonDocument` and `Utf8JsonReader` work directly with `byte` spans rather than strings or `char` spans, like so:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonDocument JsonDocumentFromObject<TValue>(TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options = default) 
        => JsonDocumentFromObject(value, typeof(TValue), options);

    public static JsonDocument JsonDocumentFromObject(object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options = default)
    {
        var bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(value, type, options);
        return JsonDocument.Parse(bytes);
    }

    public static JsonElement JsonElementFromObject<TValue>(TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options = default)
        => JsonElementFromObject(value, typeof(TValue), options);

    public static JsonElement JsonElementFromObject(object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options = default)
    {
        using var doc = JsonDocumentFromObject(value, type, options);
        return doc.RootElement.Clone();
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
using var doc = JsonExtensions.JsonDocumentFromObject(new MyClass { Data = "value" });
```

Or, if you need to use the root element outside the scope of a `using` statement:

```
var element = JsonExtensions.JsonElementFromObject(new MyClass { Data = "value" });
```

Notes:

- As noted above, a `JsonDocument` needs to be disposed after being created.
  The above `JsonExtensions.JsonElementFromObject()` extension methods correctly dispose of their internal document and returns a clone of the root element, as recommended in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#jsondocument-is-idisposable).
- Serializing to an intermediate Utf8 byte sequence is likely to be more performant than serializing to a `string` because, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialize-to-utf-8):

  > Serializing to UTF-8 is about 5-10% faster than using the string-based methods. The difference is because the bytes (as UTF-8) don't need to be converted to strings (UTF-16).
- For the inverse method, see *[System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fzwtqq).

Comment: Moreover, the type is not used in the code.
Bigger issue is if the object value is already a json string, See my proposed improvement.

Comment: The referenced GitHub issue states that the extension methods are included in .net 6. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274

Comment: @Coding101 - I've seen that.  I'll update the answer once .NET 6 is out of Beta and released (or, at the minimum, the [documentation for .Net 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0) is updated to include the [new APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Read.Element.cs) so I can link to them.)

Comment: @Coding101 - went ahead and updated the answer anyway.

Comment: Looks like missing to pass the `type` argument in to the `JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes` in the second function of `JsonDocumentFromObject`.

Comment: @JaneksMalinovskis - You're right.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

dbc's answer is a good start, but not enough if the object value is already a json string!
Moreover, the type is not used in his code.

Thus I propose the following improved version:

```
    public static JsonDocument JsonDocumentFromObject(object value, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        if (value is string valueStr)
        {
            try { return JsonDocument.Parse(valueStr); }
            catch {}
        }

        byte[] bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(value, options);
        return JsonDocument.Parse(bytes);
    }

    public static JsonElement JsonElementFromObject(object value, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        JsonElement result;
        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocumentFromObject(value, options))
        {
            result = doc.RootElement.Clone();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

with the following unit test (xUnit):

```
    [Fact()]
    public void JsonElementFromObjectTest()
    {
        object o = new
        {
            id = "myId",
            timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            valid = true,
            seq = 1
        };

        JsonElement element1 = JsonSerializerExtension.JsonElementFromObject(o);
        Assert.Equal(JsonValueKind.Object, element1.ValueKind);
        string oStr1 = element1.GetRawText();
        Assert.NotNull(oStr1);

        JsonElement element2 = JsonSerializerExtension.JsonElementFromObject(oStr1);
        Assert.Equal(JsonValueKind.Object, element2.ValueKind);
        string oStr2 = element2.GetRawText();
        Assert.NotNull(oStr2);

        Assert.Equal(oStr1, oStr2);
    }
```

without the direct try Parse, element2 is a JsonValueKind.String and oStr2 contains the not escaped unicode characters, thus being an invalid Json string.

Answer (score 3):

A slick approach in .NET 5 would be:

```
private JsonElement JsonElementFromObject(object value)
{
    var jsonUtf8Bytes = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(value, new JsonSerializerOptions());
    using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonUtf8Bytes);
    return doc.RootElement.Clone();
}
```

Steps:

1. Convert the value into a JSON string, encoded as UTF-8 bytes ([SerializeToUtf8Bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetoutf8bytes)).
2. Parse the JSON string ([JsonDocument.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse)).
3. Return the root element.

Comment: Why u are using `new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }` for serialization?
And also don't get why to create the additional `reader` variable with `Utf8JsonReader` instead of using just `JsonDocument.Parse(jsonUtf8Bytes)`?

Comment: Thank you @JaneksMalinovskis, you're absolutely right!
I didn't trim enough of my code when was posting the answer. Fixed it!