# How can I get complete JSON string from Utf8JsonReader?

Tags: reader, system.text.json

I'm working on custom JsonConverter (where T is base type of objects supported by this converter) and I need to implement

```
public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

method.

I have to read first property first to determine "target type" R, and then I want to pass whole JSON string to regular generic `JsonConverter<R>(string json)`.

My problem is that I can't read two times from Utf8JsonReader and I can't find any method to read it as text.

**Can I read all JSON and store it in some string buffer, so I can read it more than one time?**

*Yes, I know this will reduce performance a lot.*

Comment: You could preload into a `JsonDocument`, query the type parameter, then deserialize from the `JsonDocument`.  See [this answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59785679/3744182) to [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).  Incidentally, deserializing from a `byte []` buffer will be faster than from a string, see [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063/3744182).

Comment: Do those two questions also answer yours?

Comment: @dbc Yes, thanks. Reading everything to `JsonDocument` will do the job. Actually I'm working on polymorphic deserialization too. Why did you put this in comment?

Comment: Because I recall you had asked some other question about polymorphic deserialization a few days ago.

Comment: @dbc I remember your comment. I followed one of suggestions from that thread about polymorphic deserialization, but I haven't read all answers. Sorry for bugging you by being lazy and not reading whole thread ;)