# Query dynamic parameters. NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, mapping

I'm having small issue with using Dapper query parameters.

I have:

- WebApi to receive request with all required data (entity name, columns, filters, etc). Filter in the deepest level has this structure (this model build from api model by ctor):

```cs
    public class QueryFilterItem
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string FieldName { get; }
        public object Value { get; }
        public ComparisonType ComparisonType { get; }
    }
```

- Query executor, which handles api call

```cs
var arguments = new ExpandoObject();
// ...
arguments.TryAdd($"{filter.Name}Entity{filter.FieldName}", filter.Value);
// ... This part above is a part of another helper class, which is dynamically building filter query data

IEnumerable<dynamic> result;

using (var connection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateDbConnection())
{
    result = connection.Query(sqlQuery, arguments); // tried with wrapping into DynamicParameters
}
```

And from that code, I get this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The member MyFilterItemEntityId 
of type System.Text.Json.JsonElement cannot be used as a parameter value
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.LookupDbType(Type type, String name, Boolean demand, ITypeHandler& handler) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 418
   at Dapper.DynamicParameters.AddParameters(IDbCommand command, Identity identity) in /_/Dapper/DynamicParameters.cs:line 232
   at Dapper.DynamicParameters.Dapper.SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters.AddParameters(IDbCommand command, Identity identity) in /_/Dapper/DynamicParameters.cs:line 151
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<>c__DisplayClass165_0.<GetCacheInfo>b__0(IDbCommand cmd, Object obj) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1714
   at Dapper.CommandDefinition.SetupCommand(IDbConnection cnn, Action`2 paramReader) in /_/Dapper/CommandDefinition.cs:line 129
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__140`1.MoveNext() in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1080
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 725
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 652
   at DappertStorageTest.Cqrs.SelectQueryHandler.GetByFilters(SelectQuery query)
   at DappertStorageTest.Cqrs.SelectQueryHandler.Handle(SelectQuery query)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at MAS.DappertStorageTest.Cqrs.Infrastructure.QueryProcessor.Execute[TResult](IQuery`1 query)
   at MAS.DapperStorageTest.Controllers.DataController.Select(SelectRequest selectRequest)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
```

> Arguments values (not part of exception):
>
> sqlQuery: USE [DapperStorageTest];SELECT * FROM [Passenger] WHERE ([Id] = @MyFilterItemEntityId)
>
> Arguments: {[MyFilterItemEntityId, ValueKind = String : "7d570abd-576d-425f-9d24-d84314d299ba"]} (raw)

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Are you trying to create some sort of general "takes a string and an object and runs a dapper query and returns the result" method? Explain your use case more?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes. This is Select query, which will be called outside (from another service \ or frontend client). Case is simple - to provide uni-access to database. Client must able to configure it with dynamic filters \ filter groups. A little bit complex than EF Repository..

Comment: Is `filter.Value` a `string` or a `JsonElement`?

Comment: @xanatos `filter.value` is object. Wait a sec I  will provide more information about that in post

Comment: @bodynar yes and no... `object x = "Hello"` x is a `string` :-) ... Can you print us `filter.Value.GetType()`?

Comment: @xanatos ok. i got it. it appears that exception caused by filter builder. cuz `{Name = "JsonElement" FullName = "System.Text.Json.JsonElement"}`

Comment: @bodynar There are various `ToObject` implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193164/613130). You could try to solve do a `TryAdd(...., filter.Value.ToObject())`, or you could try to find what happens when `Value` is setted.

Comment: @xanatos Thank you for pointing on issue's heart. `JsonElement` type comes from web api, because model property have `object` type as you can see in post. Temporally switched to `string`. Will consider about returning to `object` and handling consequences of web api model mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474771/query-dynamic-parameters-notsupportedexception#comment115757035_65474771)
Exception caused by **web api model** mapping. According to api model filter value has `object` type and asp.net core mapped string into `JsonElement`. Switched from `object` to `string` type.

```cs
public class QueryFilterItem
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string FieldName { get; }
        public object Value { get; } // Here
        public ComparisonType ComparisonType { get; }
    }
```