# JsonElement GetRawText method throws "Operation is not valid" exception on empty array

Tags: c#, system.text.json, jsonserializer, jsonelement

## Situation

I am running into an issue with my implementation of .NET Core's System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.
The API which my application utilizes for getting data returns JSON in the following format:

```json
{
    "context": "SomeUnusedContextValue",
    "value": [
        {...}
    ]
}
```

I only care for the actual response, so I only need the value item.

I have written below method to get the specific property and deserialize the items into objects.

```cs
 public static async Task<T?> DeserializeResponse<T>(Stream str, string? property, CancellationToken ct)
 {
        JsonDocument jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(str, default, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (property is null) // some calls to the API do return data at root-level
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonDocument.RootElement.GetRawText());
        }

        if (!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty(property, out JsonElement parsed))
            throw new InvalidDataException($"The specified lookup property \"{property}\" could not be found.");

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(!typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
            ? parsed.EnumerateArray().FirstOrDefault().GetRawText()
            : parsed.GetRawText(), new JsonSerializerOptions
            { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault });
}
```

## Problem

Now for my problem. Sometimes I only need a single object, however even if there is only one result, the API will still return an array. Not a problem since, as can be seen in the bottom return statement, I will just enumerate the array and get the first item (or the default `null`). This seems to crash when the returned array is empty, throwing below exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.GetRawText()
   at BAS.Utilities.Deserializing.ResponseDeserializer.DeserializeResponse[T](Stream str, String property, CancellationToken ct) in C:\dev\bas.api\Modules\BAS.Utilities\Deserializing\ResponseDeserializer.cs:line 40
```

The object I'm trying to serialize into is as below:

```cs
public class JobFunctionCombination
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the combined identifier of the main function group, the function group and the sub function group.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>01_0101_010101</example>
        [JsonPropertyName("job_function_combination_id")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the combined names of the function groups.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>Management | Human Resources | Finance controller</example>
        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the identifier of the main function group.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonPropertyName("job_main_function_group_id")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string MainFunctionGroupId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the identifier of the function group.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonPropertyName("job_function_group_id")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string FunctionGroupId { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the identifier of the sub function group.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonPropertyName("job_sub_function_group_id")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public string SubFunctionGroupId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The types and JsonPropertyName attributes all match to the returned JSON.

## Attempted fixes

To try and fix this issue, I have tried some fixes (two of which you can still see in the given code samples).

- Adding the `JsonIgnore` attribute to the properties in the class.

  - I have tried to set the condition to `WhenWritingDefault` as well as `WhenWritingNull`. Neither seem to fix the problem.
- Setting the `DefaultIgnoreCondition` in a `JsonSerializerOptions` object passed to `JsonSerializer.Deserialze`.

  - Here I have also tried both `WhenWritingDefault` and `WhenWritingNull`, also to no avail.
- Checking if the array in `JsonElement`, when enumerated, is null or empty using `.isNullOrEmpty()`.

  - This does prevent the exception from occuring, however it does not seem like an actual fix to me. More like a FlexTape solution just cancelling out the exception.

I am not sure what the exact issue is, other than the clear fact that `JsonSerializer` clearly has an issue with null objects. What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with your call to `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
parsed.EnumerateArray().FirstOrDefault()
```

[`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement) is a **`struct`**, so when the array has no items, `FirstOrDefault()` will return a default struct -- one initialized with zeros but without any property values set.  Such an element does not correspond to any JSON token; [`ValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.valuekind?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-valuekind) will have the default value of [`JsonValueKind.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonvaluekind) and [`GetRawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getrawtext?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonelement-getrawtext) will have no raw text to return.  In such a situation Microsoft chose to make `GetRawText()` throw an exception rather than return a null string.

To avoid the problem, enumerate the array, use a `Select()` statement to deserialize each item, then afterwards do `FirstOrDefault()` to return `default(T)` when the array is empty, like so:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T?> DeserializeResponse<T>(Stream str, string? property, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        if (property is null) // some calls to the API do return data at root-level
        {
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(str, cancellationToken: ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        using var jsonDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(str, default, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty(property, out JsonElement parsed))
            throw new InvalidDataException($"The specified lookup property \"{property}\" could not be found.");

        return typeof(T).IsSerializedAsArray() 
            ? parsed.Deserialize<T>()
            : parsed.EnumerateArray().Select(i => i.Deserialize<T>()).FirstOrDefault();
    }       
    
    static bool IsSerializedAsArray(this Type type) =>
        type != typeof(string)
        && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        && type != typeof(byte []) // byte arrays are serialized as Base64 strings.
        && !type.IsDictionary();

    static bool IsDictionary(this Type type) =>
        typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        || type.GetInterfacesAndSelf().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>));

    static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type) =>
        (type ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()).IsInterface 
        ? new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces())
        : type.GetInterfaces();
}
```

Notes:

- Since [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) uses deferred execution, only the first element (if present) will be deserialized.
- In .NET 6 you may use [`JsonSerialzier.Deserialize(JsonElement, Type, JsonSerializerOptions = default)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize) to deserialize directly from a `JsonElement`.  In .NET 5 and earlier, use one of the `ToObject<T>()` workaround extension methods from *[System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182)*.
- I corrected the logic that tests whether the type `T` is to be serialized as an array.
- [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument) is disposable, and must be disposed of to return pooled memory to the memory pool.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/58nwHc).