# How to get value from dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I need otp value from the following dynamic otp json element I am recieving in Web API Controller. I have tried a lot of things but couldn't find.

This is how I receive in controller

[image]

Quick watch window

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138793/system-text-json-jsonelement-toobject-workaround)

Comment: You can use [`.GetProperty("otp")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getproperty) to access the internal element. That will return a new `JsonElement`, which is a string. So use `.GetString()` on that. But the better (=C# like) answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063). You need to deserialize the `JsonElement` to a proxy class or a `Dictionary<string, object>` (or `Dictionary<string, string>` for this simple type).

Answer (score 1):

As your Quick Watch shows:

[image]

When you use `dynamic` here, it won't be deserialized to an object with the properties in json, but will return a `JsonElement`.

You can use its methods to parse the json as you like. Meanwhile you can just receive it like `[FromBody] JsonElement opt`.

Comment: ah, of course. dumb of me. It should even be `[FromBody]string opt`, as `JsonElement` is not needed at all.