# System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonValue GetValue<T> after serialization

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am trying to use `JsonValue` as a property on a larger object to represent a serialized value (similar to `JToken` in Newtonsoft).

However, I am running into issues when a `JsonValue` is parsed.

```
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

record Project(string Id);

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Project("Test");
        var jval1 = JsonValue.Create(p)!;

        // This works!
        var p1 = jval1.GetValue<Project>();

        var jval2 = JsonNode.Parse(jval1.ToJsonString());

        // This does not :(
        var p2 = jval2.GetValue<Project>();
    }
}
```

I can evaluate `p1`, but not `p2`, it throws:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The node must be of type 'JsonValue'.'`

I see this is because the `JsonValue.Parse` method returns a `JsonNode` and not a `JsonValue`. But cannot find any API surface that allows for creation of `JsonValue` from string.

Comment: `GetValue<T>` is for primitives or compatible types only.  For general deserialization use the extension method  [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(this JsonNode, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59047063) to [System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793).

Comment: In fact this looks like a duplicate, agree?

Comment: The `Deserialize` method did the trick! Thanks. I agree that these two are related, but I've been using `JsonNode` derivatives not `JsonElement`.

Comment: Ah OK.  Do you need an answer then?

Comment: I’ll accept if you post an answer 