# Serialize/Deserialize a class hierarchy with .NET Core System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, polymorphism, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I have a simple class hierarchy that I want to serialize using System.Text.Json.

There are 3 classes. The base is `Shape`. Inherited ones are `Box` and `Circle`.

I have a plan to use these classes as a tagged union on my frontend app so I just introduced a discriminator property `Tag`.

I wrote a type convertor that supports serialization/deserialization of this hierarchy.

What I'm trying to understand - is this a best approach to implement such functionality or not. Indeed the output result of serialization is quite ugly (I put a comment in an example below). I'm not sure it's done the best way anyway it's just working.

Here's the example how I implemented serialization/deserialization:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Serialization.Theory
{
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        public abstract String Tag { get; }
    }

    public class Box : Shape
    {
        public override String Tag { get; } = nameof(Box);

        public Single Width { get; set; }

        public Single Height { get; set; }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return $"{Tag}: Width={Width}, Height={Height}";
        }
    }

    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public override String Tag { get; } = nameof(Circle);

        public Single Radius { get; set; }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return $"{Tag}: Radius={Radius}";
        }
    }

    public class ShapeConverter : JsonConverter<Shape>
    {
        public override Boolean CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return typeToConvert == typeof(Circle) || typeToConvert == typeof(Shape);
        }

        public override Shape Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var raw = reader.GetString();
            var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(raw);
            var prop = doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject().Where(x => x.Name == "Tag").First();
            var value = prop.Value.GetString();

            switch (value)
            {
                case nameof(Circle): 
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Circle>(raw);
                case nameof(Box):
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Box>(raw);
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Shape value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (value is Circle circle)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(circle));
            }
            else if (value is Box box)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(box));
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Keep in base class references like it's a property on another object.
            Shape origin1 = new Box { Width = 10, Height = 20 };
            Shape origin2 = new Circle { Radius = 30 };

            var settings = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            settings.Converters.Add(new ShapeConverter());

            var raw1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(origin1, settings);
            var raw2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(origin2, settings);

            Console.WriteLine(raw1); // "{\u0022Tag\u0022:\u0022Box\u0022,\u0022Width\u0022:10,\u0022Height\u0022:20}"
            Console.WriteLine(raw2); // "{\u0022Tag\u0022:\u0022Circle\u0022,\u0022Radius\u0022:30}"

            var restored1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Shape>(raw1, settings);
            var restored2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Shape>(raw2, settings);

            Console.WriteLine(restored1); // Box: Width=10, Height=20
            Console.WriteLine(restored2); // Circle: Radius=30
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @shadeglare, please see the answer in the related question (which might be cleaner): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744873/12509023
Polymorphic (de)serialization is not supported and requires a converter similar to what you wrote. There is an issue for adding polymorphic serialization support as an opt-in: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38650

Comment: You need to dispose your `JsonDocument` to avoid a memory leak, e.g. by doing `using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(raw);`  See the [doc remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) for details.

Answer (score 3):

**Update .Net 7**

Polymorphic serialization/deserialization is introduced in the latest .Net 7:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(InheritedClass), "InheritedClass")]
public class BaseClass {};
```

This will properly serialize all instances of `InheritedClass` regardless of whether they are top level properties, the object itself or deep inside the hierarchy of properties.

**Older answer**

This worked fine for me(in .Net 5):

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(myInheritedObject)
```

Then all of the properties of both base and inherited class were included. Not sure if there are any problems with this approach though...

Comment: Works great for the main object itself but be aware that it won't have the same effect on any base-typed properties of that object.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this library I wrote as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer polymorphism: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json

```
public abstract class Shape
{
}

[JsonDiscriminator(nameof(Box))]
public class Box : Shape
{
    public float Width { get; set; }

    public float Height { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Box: Width={Width}, Height={Height}";
    }
}

[JsonDiscriminator(nameof(Circle))]
public class Circle : Shape
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Circle: Radius={Radius}";
    }
}
```

Inherited classes must be manually registered to the discriminator convention registry in order to let the framework know about the mapping between a discriminator value and a type:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.SetupExtensions();
DiscriminatorConventionRegistry registry = options.GetDiscriminatorConventionRegistry();
registry.RegisterConvention(new AttributeBasedDiscriminatorConvention<string>(options, "Tag"));
registry.RegisterType<Box>();
registry.RegisterType<Circle>();

Shape origin1 = new Box { Width = 10, Height = 20 };
Shape origin2 = new Circle { Radius = 30 };

string json1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(origin1, options);
string json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(origin2, options);

Console.WriteLine(json1); // {"Tag":"Box","Width":10,"Height":20}
Console.WriteLine(json2); // {"Tag":"Circle","Radius":30}

var restored1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Shape>(json1, options);
var restored2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Shape>(json2, options);

Console.WriteLine(restored1); // Box: Width=10, Height=20
Console.WriteLine(restored2); // Circle: Radius=30
```