# System.Text.Json problem with complex interfaces

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have three classes: **Hotel** (implements IHotel) , **Room** (implements IRoom , which is inherited from IRoomDetails and IBookedRoom), **ClientModel** (implement IClientModel).

```
public interface IRoomDetails
    {
        string Number { get; set; }
        float PricePerDay { get; set; }
    }

public interface IBookedRoom
    {
        bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
        IClientModel Reservator { get; set; }
        string TermFrom { get; set; }
        string TermTo { get; set; }
        string Term { get; }
    }
public interface IRoom : IRoomDetails , IBookedRoom
    {

    }
public class Room : ObservableObject, IRoom
    {
       //Realization here
    }
```

If i try to serialize `List<IRoomDetails>` all works perfect, as well as `List<IBookedRoom>`, BUT if i create interface `IRoom` , which inherits from both of them and try to serialize `List<IRoom>`:

```
 {
    "Adress": "Pokrovska , 1B",
    "Name": "Victoria",
    "TotalRooms": 2,
    "AvailableRooms": 2,
    "Rooms": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
```

As we see data is not serialized. (List of rooms is not empty) . Any suggestions?

Comment: Using Newtonsoft.Json solved problem

Comment: Probably something to do with `System.Text.Json`'s very restricted support for polymorphism while serializing.  Polymorphic subtype properties are only serialized *when the property is declared as an `object`*.  See [Why does System.Text Json Serialiser not serialise this generic property but Json.NET does?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033671/3744182) for confirmation, and [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182) for workarounds.  Switching back to Json.NET perfectly reasonable here.

Comment: If you need further help, might you [edit] your question to include a full [mcve]?  As it is we only have some of the classes that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have already tested System.Text.Json and found out that it has very restricted support for polymorphism as you said before , so method Serialize() doesn`t work here properly. Acting in the same manner , but with Newtonsoft.Json serializer solved problem from the first time. I guess it is one of the namespace problems rather than mine.