# How to Serialize/deserialize a nested dictionary of non-enum types with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, jsonserializer, system.text.json

I am trying to serialize this dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, ResetableObjectTheme> ResetableObjectThemes = new Dictionary<string, ResetableObjectTheme>()
{
    {"ThemeDark", new ResetableObjectTheme() { ResetablePatternObject = new PatternObject(), ResetableMaterialObject = new MaterialObject()}},
    {"ThemeLight", new ResetableObjectTheme() { ResetablePatternObject = new PatternObject(), ResetableMaterialObject = new MaterialObject()}},
};

string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(ResetableObjectThemes, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
```

After that I get a wrong result string json, like this:

```
{
  "ResetableObjectThemes": {
    "ThemeDark": {
      "ResetablePatternObject": {},
      "ResetableMaterialObject": {}
    },
    "ThemeLight": {
      "ResetablePatternObject": {},
      "ResetableMaterialObject": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But it should be something like this:

```
{
  "ResetableObjectThemes": {
    "ThemeDark": {
      "ResetablePatternObject": {
        "Thickness": 3,
        "BoundaryColor": {
          "ColorContext": null,
          "A": 255,
          "R": 0,
          "G": 0,
          "B": 128,
        },
      },
      "ResetableMaterialObject": {
        "BoundaryThickness": 3,
        "BoundaryColor": {
          "ColorContext": null,
          "A": 255,
          "R": 0,
          "G": 0,
          "B": 255,       
        },
      }
    },
    "ThemeLight": {
      "ResetablePatternObject": {
        "Thickness": 3,
        "BoundaryColor": {
          "ColorContext": null,
          "A": 255,
          "R": 0,
          "G": 0,
          "B": 128,
        },
      },
      "ResetableMaterialObject": {
        "BoundaryThickness": 3,
        "BoundaryColor": {
          "ColorContext": null,
          "A": 255,
          "R": 0,
          "G": 0,
          "B": 255,
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The classes are:

```
public class ResetableObjectTheme
{
    public ResetableBaseObject ResetablePatternObject { get; set; } = new PatternObject();
    public ResetableBaseObject ResetableMaterialObject { get; set; } = new MaterialObject();
}

public class PatternObject : ResetableBaseObject
{
    public double Thickness { get; set; } = 1;
    public Color BoundaryColor { get; set; } = Colors.Blue;
}
public class MaterialObject : ResetableBaseObject
{
    public double BoundaryThickness { get; set; } = 3;
    public Color BoundaryColor { get; set; } = Colors.Blue;
}
```

and ResetableBaseObject is just a base class containing a common method.
I had already using this approach for another stuff where instead of type ResetableBaseObject, were used an enumeration and the serialization/deserialization worked perfectly.
The reason for using a dictionary is that this way I can dynamically set values according to some UI theme:

```
ResetableObjectThemes[ThemeManager.CurrentTheme].ResetablePatternObject = new PatternObject() { Thickness = 5.5 };
```

Why is System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize/Deserialize not able to do the job for nested non-enum types?

Comment: `System.Text.Json` does not serialize properties of derived classes.  This is the documented behavior, see [Why does System.Text Json Serialiser not serialise this generic property but Json.NET does?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033671/3744182).  If you want to serialize and deserialize a class hierarchy you will need to create a custom converter, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: Alternatively you could eliminate the requirement to serialize and deserialize class hierarchies by declaring  declare `public class ResetableObjectTheme { public PatternObject ResetablePatternObject { get; set; } public  MaterialObject ResetableMaterialObject { get; set; } }`

Comment: @dbc yes, you are right. Just modified the property types. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using polymorphism for the properties of `ResetableObjectTheme`, and `System.Text.Json` does not support polymorphism by default.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism):

> Serialization of a polymorphic type hierarchy is *not* supported. For example, if a property is defined as an interface or an abstract class, only the properties defined on the interface or abstract class are serialized, even if the runtime type has additional properties.
> The exceptions to this behavior are explained in this section...

The simplest way around the limitation is to declare the properties of `ResetableObjectTheme` to be the appropriate derived type:

```
public class ResetableObjectTheme 
{ 
    public PatternObject ResetablePatternObject { get; set; } 
    public MaterialObject ResetableMaterialObject { get; set; } 
}
```

If you actually need to serialize and deserialize polymorphic subtypes, you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization) as shown in e.g. *[Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182)*.