# Serialize a generic list with properties of different type of classes

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        
        var shapes = new List<Shape>();
        shapes.Add(new Circle { Name = "Circle1", Diameter = 2.0});
        shapes.Add(new Circle { Name = "Circle2", Diameter = 2.0});
        
        shapes.Add(new Rectangle { Name = "Rect1", Length = 2.0});
        shapes.Add(new Rectangle { Name = "Rect2", Length = 2.0});
        
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(shapes);
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
    }
    
    
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        public string Name { get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Circle:Shape
    {
        public double Diameter { get;set;}
    }
    public class Rectangle:Shape
    {
        public double Length {get;set;}
    }   
    
}
```

When serializing, i am losing properties of rectangle and circle, only getting the ones from Shape.

This is the outpout

> [{"Name":"Circle1"},{"Name":"Circle2"},{"Name":"Rect1"},{"Name":"Rect2"}]

Which is expected, given that the serializer thinks they are all "Shape", how can i make it so that its smart enough to serialize to proper sub classes

Comment: Are you going to use Text.Json onlly or open to Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: hoping to stick to Text.Json if possible,

Comment: if you want to stick with Text.Json look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json . Newtonsoft makes it much easier.

Comment: But the main problem is to deserialize from json

Comment: System.Text.Json only serializes the properties of the **declared** type - here `Shape` - rather than the actual, concrete type - here `Circle` and `Rectangle`.  See [Why does System.Text Json Serialiser not serialise this generic property but Json.NET does?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033671/3744182).  If you only need to serialize, you could serialize a `List<object>` rather than a `List<Shape>` and the actual concrete type will be serialized. But if you need to deserialize, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).

Comment: Do those two questions answer yours also?

Answer (score 0):

you can make your code much more simple if changes your base class

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```

in this case you can initiate objects more simple and safe way. Also I recommend to use Newtonsoft.Json. It will make your life much easier

```
    var origShapes = new List<Shape>();

    origShapes.Add(new Circle {  Diameter = 2.0 });
    origShapes.Add(new Circle { Diameter = 2.0 });
    origShapes.Add(new Rectangle {  Length = 2.0 });
    origShapes.Add(new Rectangle { Length = 2.0 });

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(origShapes, 
                            Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Diameter": 2.0,
    "Name": "Circle"
  },
  {
    "Diameter": 2.0,
    "Name": "Circle"
  },
  {
    "Length": 2.0,
    "Name": "Rectangle"
  },
  {
    "Length": 2.0,
    "Name": "Rectangle"
  }
]
```

To deserialize you can use this code

```
    List<Shape> shapesBack = JArray.Parse(json)
         .Select(o => (Shape)JsonConvert
        .DeserializeObject(o.ToString(), Type.GetType((string)o["Name"]))).ToList();
```

or a custom converter

```
List<Shape> shapesBack  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Shape>>(json, 
                             new CollectionFromBaseConverter());

public class CollectionFromBaseConverter : JsonConverter<List<Shape>>
{
    public override List<Shape> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<Shape> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
       .Select(o => (Shape)JsonConvert
      .DeserializeObject(o.ToString(), Type.GetType((string)o["Name"]))).ToList();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<Shape> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Test

```
    foreach (var shape in shapesBack)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(shape.GetType().Name);
    }
```

test result

```
Circle
Circle
Rectangle
Rectangle
```