# System.Text.Json Custom Seriallization / Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, .net-standard-2.1

I have the following class:

```
public class PropoertyValue {
 string Id {get;set;}
 object Value {get;set;}
 string Type {get;set;}
```

}

When I serialize/deserialize Json I want the value property reflects the type specified in "Type" property. How can I do this?

Here Sample:
Json: `{"Id":"Property1","Value":0,"Type":"System.Int32"}` // The Type must by any POCO object type.

When Deserialized I would call a PropertyValue class method that return the value:

```
public getValue<T>() => (T)Value;
```

Can anyone help me with serialization/deserialization of the PropertyValue type?

Comment: You can refer to [Support polymorphic deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-polymorphic-deserialization) article and write your own converter to handle the `Type` property. Answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/4728685) also may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your JSON deserializes to class, object property converts to the JsonElement.with this Extension Method, you can convert your JsonElement to every type you want.

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element)
{
  if (element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Null)
      return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(element.GetRawText());
  return default(T);
}
```

you can use it like this code :

```
var model = new PropoertyValue();
model.Value = 0;
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PropoertyValue>(jsonString);
var yourObject = ((JsonElement)data.Value).ToObject<int>();
```

Now **yourObject** variable type is Int32.

You have another approach; you can use the second model for deserializing.

```
public class DeserializeModel {
  string Id {get;set;}
  JsonElement Value {get;set;}
  string Type {get;set;}
}
```

subsequently :

```
var model = new PropoertyValue();
model.Value = 0;
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model);
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DeserializeModel>(jsonString);
var yourObject = data.Value.ToObject<int>();
```

Comment: But you are doing 2 deserializations, better way is to use a custom converter.