# ASP .Net Core – Polymorphic DTOs

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm developing the ASP .Net "Student Testing" Rest API.
I'm using the default `System.Text.Json` (de)serializer with the .net v5.0

This API is used for student testing.
The student chooses a test from the list and takes it.

There are several types of questions in my API:

- Text question - the student enters the answer into the input field
- Single choice question - the student chooses one of the proposed options
- Multiple choice question - the student chooses multiple options

After the student is confident in his answers, he submits them.
Here is an example of the submitted answers in JSON format:

```json
{
  "testId": "07450745-0745-0745-0745-074507450745",
  "answeredQuestions": [
    {
      "id": "abcdabcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdabcdabcd",
      "type": "text",
      "givenAnswer": "Answer that student typed in the input box."
    },
    {
      "id": "88888888-4444-4444-4444-dddddddddddd",
      "type": "single-choice",
      "selectedAnswerOptionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000008"
    },
    {
      "id": "12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234",
      "type": "multiple-choice",
      "selectedAnswerOptionIds": [
        "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
        "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
        "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have DTO questions implemented in ASP .Net Core API:

```csharp
public abstract class AnsweredQuestion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}

public class AnsweredTextQuestion : AnsweredQuestion
{
    public override string Type => "text";
    public string GivenAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class AnsweredSingleChoiceQuestion : AnsweredQuestion
{
    public override string Type => "single-choice";
    public Guid SelectedAnswerOptionId { get; set; }
}

public class AnsweredMultipleChoiceQuestion : AnsweredQuestion
{
    public override string Type => "multiple-choice";
    public ICollection<Guid> SelectedAnswerOptionIds { get; set; }
}
```

But I'm not really sure how to implement the presented test DTO.
If I just do something like `ICollection<AnsweredQuestion>` for the JSON `answeredQuestions` field, then all data related to the specific question type is lost (e.g. `givenAnswer`, `selectedAnswerOptionId` or `selectedAnswerOptionIds`).

How to implement the submitted test DTO to support different types of questions?

In all my actions JSON deserialization happens automatically, but in that case it can be a problem.
I think the solution is to somehow change the deserialization logic to take into account the value of the `type` field.

Comment: Are you using System.Text.Json (default since ASP.NET Core 3.1) or Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: I'm using `System.Text.Json` (de)serializer with the .net v5.0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you define am enum of the type of questions.

```csharp
public enum QuestionType
{
    TextQuestion,
    SingleChoice, 
    MultipleChoice
}
```

Then you define a single table for all your question types

```csharp
public class Question
{
    public int Id{get; set;} 
    public QuestionType QuestionType{get;set;} 
    public string TextQuestionAnswer{get;set;} 
    public int SingleChoiceAnswer{get;set;} 
    public ICollection<MultipleChoice> MultipleChoiceAnswers{get;set;}
}

public class MultipleChoice
{
    public int Id{get;set;} 
    public int QuestionId
    public int SelectedAnswerId{get;set;} 
    public Question Question{get;set;}
}
```

So, in your controllers, you will definite a logic that checks if a question is of a certain type, if it is, then only allow answers to be saved for that type, and the other types will be null.

For example, if a question is of type SingleChoice, then only the SingleChoiceAnswer property will have a value saved, other MultipleChoiceAnswers and TextQuestionAnswer properties will be null.

Comment: I also thought about a similar approach.
This is somewhat similar to the Table-Per-Hierarchy from Entity Framework Core.
I don't like this approach because I am using a language with an OOP paradigm.
Somehow it seems wrong to me to create a class that represents several different entities at the same time.
So I decided to abandon this approach in favor of the one suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744873/13851956).

Comment: @catman0745 Yeah. I know it's not so good. I used the approach in a project, wish I had seen the suggested answer before.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the help in solving the problem.