# .NET Core Serialize Inherited Class Properties -- Not Just Base Properties When Preserving References

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

We have a problem when serializing using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.

In this example, we have three classes: `Store`, `Employee`, and `Manager`.  It is noted that Manager inherits from Employee.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Employee
{
    public int AllowedPersonalDays { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public Employee EmployeeOfTheMonth { get; set; }

    public Manager Manager { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the class `Store`, we have a property called `EmployeeOfTheMonth`.  Well, as an example, suppose this property referenced the same object as the `Manager` property.  Because `EmployeeOfTheMonth` is serialized first, it will ONLY serialize the `Employee` properties.  When serializing the `Manager` property -- because it is second and the same object -- it will add a reference to the `EmployeeOfTheMonth`.  When we do this, we're losing the additional property attached to the `Manager`, which is `AllowedPersonalDays`.  Additionally, as you can see, it will not deserialize because -- while a Manager is an Employee -- an Employee is not a Manager.

Here's our short example:

```
Manager mgr = new Manager()
{
    Age = 42,
    AllowedPersonalDays = 14,
    Name = "Jane Doe",
};

Store store = new Store()
{
    EmployeeOfTheMonth = mgr,
    Manager = mgr,
    Name = "ValuMart"
};

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();
options.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve;

string serialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<Store>(store, options);
var deserialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Store>(serialized, options); // <-- Will through an exception per reasons stated above
```

If we look at the variable `serialized`, this is the content:

```
{
  "$id":"1",
  "EmployeeOfTheMonth": {
    "$id":"2",
    "Name":"Jane Doe",
    "Age":42
  },
  "Manager": {
    "$ref":"2"
  },
  "Name":"ValuMart"
}
```

Using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, how can we get the `EmployeeOfTheMonth` to correctly serialize as a `Manager`?  That is, we need the serialization to look like the following:

```
{
  "$id":"1",
  "EmployeeOfTheMonth": {
    "$id":"2",
    "Name":"Jane Doe",
    "Age":42,
    "AllowedPersonalDays":14         <-- We need to retain this property even if the EmployeeOfTheMonth is a Manager
  },
  "Manager": {
    "$ref":"2"
  },
  "Name":"ValuMart"
}
```

I know I can adjust the ORDER of the properties in the `Store` class, but this is not an option and a very poor choice.  Thank you, all.

Comment: I think you can workaround this issue using custom serializer which will support typehandling-like serialization/deserialization (using some [discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744873/2501279), not actual type).

Comment: Do you need to **deserialize**, or just serialize?

Comment: If you need to deserialize as well as serialize, the requirement to combine reference tracking with a custom converter is tricky -- and not directly supported by MSFT, see [ ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles doesn't work with Custom Converters #51715 ](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/51715).  But if you only need to serialize there are some fairly simple approaches to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, we need to serialize as well as deserialize.  I think I need to create a custom converter.  Thank you, all, for your assistance.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764443/3744182) by [Alexander Sheremetyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8362084/alexander-sheremetyev) to [Resolve cycle references of complex type during JSON serialization using System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69741572/3744182) shows how to write a custom converter that also emits reference information.  Doing so requires implementing a custom `ReferenceHandler` since MSFT doesn't make their internal reference handler available to the converter as of .NET 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on writing custom converters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json/59744873#59744873) has a very similar example (discriminating between two subclasses of a property's declared type) and could be adapted as follows:

```
public class EmployeeConverter : JsonConverter<Employee>
{
    enum TypeDiscriminator
    {
        Employee = 1,
        Manager = 2
    }

    private static string s_typeDiscriminatorLabel = "$TypeDiscriminator";

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) =>
        typeof(Employee).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override Employee Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        string propertyName = reader.GetString();
        if (propertyName != s_typeDiscriminatorLabel)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        reader.Read();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        // Instantiate type based on type discriminator value
        TypeDiscriminator typeDiscriminator = (TypeDiscriminator)reader.GetInt32();
        Employee employee = typeDiscriminator switch
        {
            TypeDiscriminator.Employee => new Employee(),
            TypeDiscriminator.Manager => new Manager(),
            _ => throw new JsonException()
        };

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return employee;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        string name = reader.GetString();
                        employee.Name = name;
                        break;
                    case "Age":
                        int age = reader.GetInt32();
                        employee.Age = age;
                        break;
                    case "AllowedPersonalDays":
                        int allowedPersonalDays = reader.GetInt32();
                        if(employee is Manager manager)
                        {
                            manager.AllowedPersonalDays = allowedPersonalDays;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new JsonException();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer, Employee person, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        // Write type indicator based on whether the runtime type is Manager
        writer.WriteNumber(s_typeDiscriminatorLabel, (int)(person is Manager ? TypeDiscriminator.Manager : TypeDiscriminator.Employee));

        writer.WriteString("Name", person.Name);
        writer.WriteNumber("Age", person.Age);

        // Write Manager-ony property only if runtime type is Manager
        if(person is Manager manager)
        {
            writer.WriteNumber("AllowedPersonalDays", manager.AllowedPersonalDays);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Add an instance of your custom converter and it should deserialize correctly:

```
options.Converters.Add(new EmployeeConverter());

string serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Store>(store, options);
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Store>(serialized, options);
string reserialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Store>(deserialized, options);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(serialized == reserialized, "Manager property should be retained");
```

Comment: This doesn't actually generate the required `"$id"` and `"$ref"` properties though, does it?