# Serialize and deserialize derived classes with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json

I'm tried to object a JSON with `System.Text.Json` from my class. I have a base class called `Element` that is defined like this

```
public interface IElement
{
    public string? Type { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have few classes that inherit from it, for example

```
public class Textbox : IElement
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public virtual string? Type { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
}

public class Radiobutton : IElement
{
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public virtual string? Type { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("choises")]
    public List<string> Choises = new List<string>();
}
```

Now, I want to have a class that defines the form with all the elements

```
public class Form
{
    [JsonPropertyName("elements")]
    public List<IElement> Elements { get; set; } = new List<IElement>();
}
```

After that, I define the form

```
Form form = new Form()
{
    Elements = new List<IElement>()
    {
        new Textbox() { Name = "txt1", Type = "Textbox", Text = "One" },
        new Radiobutton() { 
            Name = "radio1", Type = "Radiobutton",
            Choices = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" }}
    }
};
```

If I create the JSON from this object, it has only the common fields

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "Textbox",
      "name": "txt1",
    },
    {
      "type": "Radiobutton",
      "name": "radio1",
    }
  ]
}
```

The fields `Text` for the Textbox or `Choices` for the Radiobutton are ignored. I read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism): I tried the code

```
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(weatherForecast, options);
```

but I obtained the same result.

How can I create the JSON with all the details of the `Form` object regardless of the type of `Element`? Viceversa, when I have the JSON, how can I deserialize it in the `Form` class?

Comment: *If I create the JSON from this object, it has only the common fields*, of course it is the expected behavior due to the concept of inheritance, upcasting in this case.

Comment: My usuall advise is to forget about Text.Json , use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I have to say that `System.Text.Json` is working quite well and better than `Newtonsoft.Json`. I added a help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true
};

jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, weatherForecast.GetType(), options);
```

Comment: Tried but it is not working