# System.Text.Json .NET 8 Polymorphic deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json, .net-8.0

When I try to perform a polymorphic deserialization in a .net 8 application using System.Text.Json I have the described issues.

I have the following interfaces and classes

```
public interface IBaseMessage
{
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SpecificMessage))]
public interface ISpecificMessage :
    IBaseMessage,
    ISomething
{
}

public class SpecificMessage
{
    public IBaseMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I receive a request with an `ISpecific` type in `IBaseMessage Messages` I expect to end up with my `SpecificMessage` data deserialized but I end up with a **null** `IBaseMessage` (no exception thrown).

I've tried to use the following attributes on `IBaseMessage` but it throws the following exception: `Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'IBaseMessage'.`

`[JsonPolymorphic(UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FallBackToNearestAncestor)] [JsonDerivedType(typeof(ISpecificMessage))]`

I am trying to solve this using some attributes, not adding custom converters if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifing all the descendants with discriminants on the base interface:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(SpecificMessage), typeDiscriminator: nameof(SpecificMessage)]
public interface IBaseMessage
{
}

public interface ISpecificMessage : IBaseMessage
{
}

public class SpecificMessage : ISpecificMessage
{
}

class MyClass
{
    public IBaseMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

You can test the hierarchy:

```
var serialize = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyClass()
{
    Message = new SpecificMessage()
});
Console.WriteLine(serialize); // prints {"Message":{"$type":"SpecificMessage"}}


var deserialize = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(serialize);
Console.WriteLine(deserialize .Message.GetType()); // prints SpecificMessage
```

If you have multi-level type hierarchy you can try automating it - see [How can I serialize a multi-level polymorphic type hierarchy with System.Text.Json in .NET 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74604551/2501279) for some examples.

Comment: Yep, adding that typeDiscriminator did the trick, for some reason I though I already tried that. Thanks!