# Polymorphic deserialization of Dictionary with Interface values always returns null using System.Text.Json

Tags: json, serialization, system.text.json

I am trying to JSON serialize and deserialize the class PlanningData to a database. Serialization seems to work but when deserializing Dictionary<SomeEnum, MyInterface> always returns null even though I can correctly navigate the Dictionary keys and values in the Visual Studio JSON viewer when deserializing.

I am using Net 8 so I tried implementing this:
[System.Text.Json .NET 8 Polymorphic deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77886914/system-text-json-net-8-polymorphic-deserialization)

and dbc's answer here:
[Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074304/is-polymorphic-deserialization-possible-in-system-text-json)

but I could not get it to work, i.e. deserialization still returned null.

This is the code to set up serialization for the database:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
                .Property(c => c.PlanningData)
                .HasColumnName("PlanningData")
                .HasConversion(
                    v => JsonHelper.Serialize(v),
                    v => JsonHelper.Deserialize<PlanningData>(v)
                );
```

```
    public class PlanningData
    {
        public required ProfitLossData ProfitLossData { get; init; }
    }
```

```
    public class ProfitLossData
    {
// Deserialization of this property always returns null
        public Dictionary<string, List<ProfitLossDataLineItem>> ProfitLossDataLineItems { get; private set;}
    }
```

```
    public class ProfitLossDataLineItem : DataLineItem
    {
    }
```

```
public class DataLineItem
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(PlanningCalculatedResultConverter))]
    public Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption> AllPlanningCellValueObjects { get; set; } = new Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption>
                                        {
                                            { PlanningType.A, new Class1ThatImplementsInterface() },
                                            { PlanningType.B, new Class2ThatImplementsInterface() },
                                            { PlanningType.C, new Class3ThatImplementsInterface() },
                                            { PlanningType.D, new Class4ThatImplementsInterface() },
                                            { PlanningType.E, new Class5ThatImplementsInterface()},                        
    };
}
```

```
    public static class JsonHelper
    {
        static readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options = new()
        {
            Converters = { new PlanningCalculatedResultConverter(), new NullableObjectArrayConverter()  }
        };

        public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
        {
            return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
        {
// this never calls my PlanningCalculatedResultConverter
            var deserializedValue = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, _options) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Deserialization returned null.");
            return deserializedValue;
        }
    }
```

```
public class PlanningCalculatedResultConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption>>
{
    public override Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Deserialize the JSON to a JsonDocument
        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption>();

            // Iterate over each property in the JSON document
            foreach (var property in doc.RootElement.EnumerateObject())
            {
                // Parse the PlanningType from the property name
                if (Enum.TryParse<PlanningType>(property.Name, out var planningType))
                {
                    // Deserialize the value to the appropriate type
                    var value = DeserializePlanningCalculatedResult(property.Value, planningType, options);

                    // Add the deserialized value to the dictionary
                    dictionary.Add(planningType, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new JsonException($"Unsupported PlanningType: {property.Name}");
                }
            }

            return dictionary;
        }
    }

    private IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption DeserializePlanningCalculatedResult(JsonElement element, PlanningType planningType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (planningType)
        {
            case PlanningType.A:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1ThatImplementsInterface>(element.GetRawText(), options);
            case PlanningType.B:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class2ThatImplementsInterface>(element.GetRawText(), options);
            case PlanningType.C:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class3ThatImplementsInterface>(element.GetRawText(), options);
            case PlanningType.D:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class4ThatImplementsInterface>(element.GetRawText(), options);
            case PlanningType.E:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class5ThatImplementsInterfaceatedResult>(element.GetRawText(), options);
            default:
                throw new JsonException($"Unsupported PlanningType: {planningType}");
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<PlanningType, IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (var kvp in value)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key.ToString());

            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, kvp.Value, kvp.Value.GetType(), options);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

```
    public interface IPlanningCalculatedResultAndRequiredInputDataForSingleOption
    {
        public bool IsOptionInDefaultState => InputParameters.Values.All(x => x.IsParameterInDefaultState);
        public double?[] CalculatedOptionResult { get; set; }

        public PlanningType PlanningType { get; } 
        public Dictionary<InputParameter, ISingleInputParameter> InputParameters { get; }
    }

    public interface ISingleInputParameter
    {
        public bool IsParameterInDefaultState => InputValues.Length == 0;

        public double[] InputValues { get; set; }

        public string InputParameterName { get; set; }

        public bool IsPercentageData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of a converter, have you considered using System.Text.Json's [built-in support for polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0)?  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182) to [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).

Comment: I added the JsonDerivedType with the types of all the classes implementing the interfaces. now i can see a $type value in the serialized JSON (see screenshot) but the deserialized object will show the dictionary ProfitLossDataItems with zero keys/values.

Comment: `ProfitLossDataLineItems` has a private setter.  You need to make the setter public or use [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute).  See [Use System.Text.Json to deserialize properties with private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62270834), which looks to be a duplicate.  Does that work?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I am considering deleting the question as it turns out that the existing answers on the other questions can indeed also answer this question.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped.  I went ahead and marked it a dup of the two other questions.