# How do I create a class with inherited members using JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, .net-core, system.text.json

I would like to create an invoice from a JSON string.

If the json string contains a certain keyword, I want to have a sub class of it. In the example below, I want to create an invoice variable that is of the type AppleInvoice.

However, I am not getting the syntax right.

At first, I have tried using Utf8JsonReader which is obsolete, and then I tried MemoryStream, but that doesn't it either.

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.Json
Imports System.Text.Json.Nodes
Imports System.Text.Json.Serialization

Public Class InvoiceConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter(Of Invoice)

    Public Overrides Function Read(ByVal reader As Utf8JsonReader, ByVal typeToConvert As Type, ByVal options As JsonSerializerOptions) As Invoice
        Dim stream As MemoryStream = DirectCast(reader, MemoryStream)
        Using doc As JsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(stream)
            Dim jsonObject As JsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of JsonObject)(doc.RootEle

ment.GetRawText())

                If jsonObject.ContainsKey("AppleID") Then
                    Return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of AppleInvoice)(jsonObject.ToString(), options)
                End If

                Return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of Invoice)(jsonObject.ToString(), options)
            End Using
        End Function

        Public Overrides Sub Write(ByVal writer As Utf8JsonWriter, ByVal value As Invoice, ByVal options As JsonSerializerOptions)
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Invoice
        Public Property InvoiceNumber As String
        Public Property InvoiceDate As DateTime
        Public Property Subtotal As Decimal
        Public Property TaxRate As Decimal
        Public Property TaxAmount As Decimal
        Public Property Total As Decimal
        Public Property CustomerName As String
        Public Property CustomerAddress As String
        Public Property Items As List(Of InvoiceItem)

        Public Sub New()
            Items = New List(Of InvoiceItem)()
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class InvoiceItem
        Public Property ProductName As String
        Public Property Quantity As Integer
        Public Property Price As Decimal
        Public Property TaxRate As Decimal
    End Class

    Public Class AppleInvoice
        Inherits Invoice
        Public Property AppleID As String
        Public Property DeviceNumber As String
        Public Property SerialNumber As String

    End Class
```

Comment: Do [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744873/3744182) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352365/3744182) to [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182) answer your question?