# CastException when serializing derived class with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-7.0, system.text.json

I've got a simple CLI app that gets some different data depending on `args` and then JSON serializes it using `System.Text.Json`.

The problem I'm running into is when serializing a derived class (ie. `List<DerivedImage>` in this case) with a custom converter for the base class (ie. `ImageConverter`).

```cs
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
  object data = "images ls" switch
  {
    "images ls" => new List<DerivedImage>() { new DerivedImage() },
    // ... etc ...
  };

  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
  {
    Converters = { new ImageConverter() }
  };

  var stringified = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
  // ^ THIS ERRORS!
  // Exception message:
  // System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'ImageConverter'
  // to type 'JsonConverter[DerivedImage]'

  return 1;
}

public class ImageConverter : JsonConverter<Image>
{
  public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
  {
    return typeof(Image).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);
  }

  public override Image Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Image value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
  {
    // It never gets here.
  }
}

public abstract class Image { }

public class DerivedImage : Image { }
```

With the snippet above, how can I get the serializer to use the `ImageConverter` when passed `data`?

Comment: While `Image` and `DerivedImage` are related by inheritance, `JsonConverter<Image>` and `JsonConverter<DerivedImage>` are not. So, since `ImageConverter` is-a `JsonConverter<Image>`, it still cannot be cast to `JsonConverter<DerivedImage>`.

Comment: @dbc Got it, example is runnable now

@Fildor-standswithMods Is there some other way to make the `ImageConverter` usable by its derived classes? I'd imagine it'd work if I create a converter for each derived class (ie. `JsonConverter<DerivedImage>`), but that'd get repetitive

Comment: Your newest code runs successfully without an `InvalidCastException` when I add some logic into `ImageConverter.Write()`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/eziNWz.  We still need to see a [mcve].

Comment: By the way, .NET 7 has built-in support for polymorphism, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182) to [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).  If the only purpose of your converter is to support polymorphism, you could consider switching to the builtin mechanism.

Comment: Wow, you're completely right. I was actually running this with `.net6` originally as the target framework, but it works completely fine with `.net7` as the target instead. Also, thanks for the advice regarding built-in polymorphic support in .NET 7. I reckon I'll still stick with a custom converter though - I have a lot of custom logic for how the JSON should be formatted in the real use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading `TargetFramework` in the project config from `.net6` to `.net7`.