# C# Polymorphic Deserialization of Bookmarks file

Tags: c#, .net-core, json-deserialization, system.text.json, polymorphic-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a Bookmarks file. Specifically using polymorphic deserialization without Newtonsoft. When running I get an exception in the Read method of the converter class, at return for case "folder".  It looks like I need some sort of constructor for either folder or its base class.  I tried using the [JsonConstructor] attribute in each class but no luck.

Additionally, when I omit the getter and setter for Folder's FolderElement list the program compiles and runs but in the JSON output only the objects of type 'folder' are created, and they are missing the 'children' properties.

Model

```
public abstract class BookmarkElement
{
    public BookmarkElement() {}
    [JsonPropertyName("date_added")]
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("date_last_used")]
    public string DateLastUsed { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("guid")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Bookmark : BookmarkElement
{
    public Bookmark() { }
    [JsonPropertyName("url")]
    public string Url {get; set;}
}

public class Folder : BookmarkElement
{
    public Folder() {}
    [JsonPropertyName("date_modified")]
    public string DateModified { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("children")]
    public List<BookmarkElement> FolderElements {get; set;}
}

public class Root : BookmarkElement
{
    public Root() {}
    [JsonPropertyName("date_modified")]
    public string DateModified { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("children")]
    public List<BookmarkElement> RootFolder { get; set; }
}

public class BookmarkModel
{
    public BookmarkModel() {}
    [JsonPropertyName("checksum")]
    public string Checksum { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("roots")]
    public Dictionary<string, Root> Roots { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Converter

```
public class BookmarkElementConverter : JsonConverter<BookmarkElement>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => 
        typeof(BookmarkElement).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override BookmarkElement? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject) throw new JsonException();

        using (var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            if(!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty("type", out var typeProperty)) throw new JsonException();

            var jsonType = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetRawText();

            switch(typeProperty.GetString())
            {
                case "url":
                    return (Bookmark)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonType, typeof(Bookmark));
                case "folder":
                    return (Folder)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonType, typeof(Folder));
                default:
                    throw new JsonException();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BookmarkElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is Bookmark bookmark)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, bookmark);
        }
        else if (value is Folder folder)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, folder);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Bookmarks file

```
{
   "checksum": "cc1f5c62ec7814f7928e2befab26c311",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
            "children": [  ],
            "date_added": "13335767383821356",
            "date_last_used": "0",
            "date_modified": "13335767383821356",
            "guid": "efeb5549-612d-4656-8982-a17069075213",
            "id": "13",
            "name": "test",
            "type": "folder"
         }, {
            "date_added": "13335767548044529",
            "date_last_used": "0",
            "guid": "df7a482b-c1c5-4aa2-af8e-8cee539513d9",
            "id": "15",
            "name": "DuckDuckGo — Privacy, simplified.",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "https://duckduckgo.com/"
         } ],
         "date_added": "13335764354355200",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "13335767548044529",
         "guid": "0bc5d13f-2cba-5d74-951f-3f233fe6c908",
         "id": "1",
         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "other": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13335764354355201",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "82b081ec-3dd3-529c-8475-ab6c344590dd",
         "id": "2",
         "name": "Other bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      },
      "synced": {
         "children": [  ],
         "date_added": "13335764354355202",
         "date_last_used": "0",
         "date_modified": "0",
         "guid": "4cf2e351-0e85-532b-bb37-df045d8f8d0f",
         "id": "3",
         "name": "Mobile bookmarks",
         "type": "folder"
      }
   },
   "version": 1
}
```

Exception

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.NotSupportedException
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'BookmarkReader.Model.BookmarkElement'. Path: $.children[0] | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 24.'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.NotSupportedException : Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'BookmarkReader.Model.BookmarkElement'.
```

Comment: Don't know, lots of questions get downvoted for no obvious reason.  Your question's JSON sample is kind of complicated but it has to be because the problem is only surfaced when `BookmarkElement` objects are nested and the converter needs to call itself recursively.  The only thing you might have done to improve the question is to show your `JsonSerializerOptions` and your call to `JsonSerializer.Serialize()`.  As it is you only have 98% of a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because, at some point, your converter is not getting picked up, and your code is attempting to deserialize an object of type `BookmarkElement`, which is abstract, and so cannot be constructed.  Microsoft's error message text is misleading, so see [demo fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FHtFkN) which completely omits the converter for confirmation.

To resolve the problem, fix `BookmarkElementConverter().Read()` so that the incoming options (which will include `BookmarkElementConverter` in the converters list) are passed into `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()`.  You need to do this because your `BookmarkElement` data model is **recursive** and thus the converter must also be invoked recursively.  And you must also fix `CanConvert()` to return true **only for the abstract type `BookmarkElement`**.  This is the default behavior so you can just remove your override.  The converter is not necessary for the derived concrete types, and if you attempt to use the converter for the derived types you will get a stack overflow exception.

Thus `BookmarkElementConverter` should look like the following, with some code simplifications:

```
public class BookmarkElementConverter : JsonConverter<BookmarkElement>
{
    public override BookmarkElement? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if(reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject) 
            throw new JsonException();

        using (var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            if(!jsonDocument.RootElement.TryGetProperty("type", out var typeProperty)) 
                throw new JsonException();
            return typeProperty.GetString() switch
            {
                "url" => jsonDocument.RootElement.Deserialize<Bookmark>(options),
                "folder" => jsonDocument.RootElement.Deserialize<Folder>(options),
                _ => throw new JsonException(),
            };
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BookmarkElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
}
```

Then when you deserialize, be sure to include `BookmarkElementConverter` in your `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new BookmarkElementConverter() },
    // Add any additional required options here:
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BookmarkModel>(json, options);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4iobQh).

Comment: thank you for that detailed answer.  it will take me some time to un pack all of that. marking as the accepted answer though i cannot get it to run correctly locally like in the demo site, but im sure thats my fault.  thanks!

Comment: @NotIntelligentException - what .NET version are you using?  I tested against .NET 7.

Comment: i am using .net 7 in my local.  have not had a change to troubleshoot since my last comment.

Comment: @NotIntelligentException - then if you are still having problems please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76937386/edit) your original question to include a [mcve] showing exactly how things fail.

Comment: @NotIntelligentException - incidentally I'd suggest making `Type` be abstract get-only (i.e. `public abstract string Type { get; }` then override it in the derived classes to return the required type identifier.  Alternatively you could switch to using .NET 7's built-in polymorphism mechanism, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182).

Comment: @NotIntelligentException - correction.  Regarding .NET 7's built in [polymorphic deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0#polymorphic-type-discriminators), it seems you can't use it after all because the `"type"` property would need to be at the beginning of each JSON object, which it isn't.  Sorry for raising a false hope.

Comment: No worries, I ended up making a new dotnet project for it and it worked.  Not sure what happened there.  thank you for the help.