# Serialize a list of generic class objects using System.Text.Json not serializing generic properties correctly

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, system.text.json

I have an application that composes algorithms. Each algorithm consists of a sequence of steps. Steps have a very similar structure, only difference being a single property that can be one of many `enum` types.

There are dozens of algorithms with hundreds of steps each. I do not want to use polymorphism as this would make the code base huge.

When using generics, the code below compiles, but produces the following output:

`{"Steps":[{"Type":"Type1","Value":{}},{"Type":"Type2","Value":{}}]}`

Instead of:

`{"Steps":[{"Type":"Type1","Value":"Bla"},{"Type":"Type2","Value":"Etc"}]}`

How can I set the System.Text.Json serializer so that it serializes the enums?

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

Algorithm algorithm1 = new Algorithm();
algorithm1.Steps = new List<Step<Enum>>()
{
    new Step<Enum>() { Type = AlgorithmType.Type1, Value = Options1.Bla },
    new Step<Enum>() { Type = AlgorithmType.Type2, Value = Options2.Etc }
};
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(algorithm1, options);
Console.WriteLine(result);


public class Algorithm
{
    public List<Step<Enum>> Steps { get; set; }
}

public class Step<T> where T : Enum
{
    public AlgorithmType Type { get; set; }
    public T? Value { get; set; }
}

public enum AlgorithmType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Type1 = 1,
    Type2 = 2,
    // elided
    Type100 = 100
}

public enum Options1
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Bla = 1,
    YadaYada = 2
}

public enum Options2
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Etc = 1,
    Eg = 2
}
```

Comment: While `Options1` and `Options2` are ("is-a") `Enum`s, neither `Step<Options1>` nor `Step<Options2>` are ("is-a") `Step<Enum>`. They are completely unrelated types.

Comment: This probably only worked so far, because Enum is somewhat special ... with an ordinary class hierarchy, the compiler would have blown up long before.

Comment: To solve the problem, I'd probably switch to a common abstraction that's based on string and int properties. Maybe like `record AlgorithmStep( int AlgorithmTypeCode, string AlgorithmTypeName, int AlgorithmStepNumber, string AlgorithmStepName)` ... maybe there's a more elegant solution, but for starters, I'd keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor. I'll consider this approach as an alternative. I feel like the serializer should be able to resolve the types involved, though. I was hoping it's just a matter of passing it the correct settings.

Comment: If they were ordinary classes, then there might have been a way with inheritance-aware serialization but enums ... meh. See also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: Anywho: If you need to model Algorithms and their steps, then doing so in the form of enums may not be the best of ideas to start with? What do you need to do to add another algo? Change `AlgorithmType` enum, create a new OptionsN enum, touch _every piece of code_ that uses AlgorithmType enum ... maybe you want to think about that. _This_ may only have been the first problem you run into with this.

Comment: The design of the real thing is actually quite easy to maintain, though it may seem otherwise from the code sample. The question is how to configure the Json serializer to serialize enums in this particular case. I did read the article you posted before posting this question, but I don't think it applies to my use case.

Comment: `System.Enum` is the abstract base type for all `enum` types, and thus represents a polymorphic type hierarchy.  Serialization of polymorphic hierarchies is generally not supported out of the box by System.Text.Json but can be enabled, see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182) for how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a custom converter:

```cs
public class CustomEnumConverter : JsonConverter<Enum> {
    public override Enum Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        Enum value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var steps = new List<Step<Enum>> {
    new Step<Enum>(Foo.Bar),
    new Step<Enum>(Zan.Gor)
};

var opts = new JsonSerializerOptions {
    Converters = { new CustomEnumConverter() }
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(steps, opts);

public record Step<T>(T Value) where T : Enum;
public enum Foo { Bar, Qux }
public enum Zan { Qel, Gor }
```

Result:

```json
[{"Value":"Bar"},{"Value":"Gor"}]
```

I doubt that this is the right approach though. How would you go about deserializing these enums?