# How can I deserialize generics by System.Text?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

Here is the class:

```
  public class TestModel<T>
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public T Parameter { get; set; }

      public DateTime Time { get; set; }
  }
```

The generic may be a string, a class, a list or so on. And also, I need to get the type of generic and do some logic after deserialized.

I have a stupid way of adding the generic type before the json in order to deserialize by its specified model (split the string and get the model by index 0), just like this.

```
string,{Name:'123',Parameter:'456',Time:'2023-12-4 06:46:01'}
```

I don't think this is a good approach. How should I implement it more appropriately?

Comment: By "System.Text" do you mean `System.Text.Json`?  If so, then maybe see [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182).  Also, do you control the JSON format, or is it fixed?

Comment: This seems like a XY problem. What could T be? Do you need to do things to T after deserialization? I think a good first step is look at the requirements again, and clarify what would be T. It should be a limited possibilities, so you can actually write the code to handle every case, and callers know what should they input.

Comment: @dbc It seems JsonDerivedType can solve this. However, I don't know why my serialized JSON always missing the $type attribute.

Comment: @dbc I solved the problem by your way. Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 3):

use your `TestModel<T>` in combination with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>` method. Here's an example :

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class TestModel<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Parameter { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\"Name\":\"Test\",\"Parameter\":42,\"Time\":\"2023-12-03T10:51:57Z\"}";

        TestModel<int> deserializedModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestModel<int>>(json);

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {deserializedModel.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {deserializedModel.Parameter}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Time: {deserializedModel.Time}");
    }
}
```

Comment: My most important problem now is that I can't predict what type of generic type of json string comes in.

Comment: In that case, modeling it as generic is not correct as the type is only known dynamically at run-time. Using non-generic type with `object` property would be a better match and give you better answers, including the fact that inheritance may or may not be a good way to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, it works above the .Net7 :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        var i = JsonSerializer.Serialize<TestModel>(new TestModelWithGeneric<string>()
        {
            Name = "123",
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Value = "123"
        });
        var j=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestModel>(i);
    }
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModel), typeDiscriminator: "Base")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModelWithGeneric<int>), typeDiscriminator: "TestModelWithInt")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestModelWithGeneric<string>), typeDiscriminator: "TestModelWithString")]
    public class TestModel {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestModelWithGeneric<T> :TestModel{ 
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```