# Can I customize and shorten the polymorphic type discriminator property name and value when serializing?

Tags: c#, serialization, polymorphism, system.text.json

Is it possible to shorten the type discriminator property name and value during serialization/deserialization? I don't have access to the types itself so in my case it should be done by configuring serializer itself. I need the property name to be `"__type"` and the property value to be some custom name.

I know that in `System.Web.Script.Serialization` `JavaScriptTypeResolver` could be used but I need to implement in .NET Core System.Text.Json.

Here is an example how it can be done using `JavaScriptTypeResolver` (the example is based on [this MS example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascripttyperesolver?view=netframework-4.8.1)):

```
var people = new Person[] { new Person { Name = "AbcPerson" } };

var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer(new CustomTypeResolver()).Serialize(people);
Console.WriteLine(serialized);

...

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomTypeResolver : JavaScriptTypeResolver
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, Type> _typeIds
        = new Dictionary<string, Type> { { "P", typeof(Person) } };

    public override Type ResolveType(string id)
    {
        _typeIds.TryGetValue(id, out var result);
        return result;
    }

    public override string ResolveTypeId(Type type)
    {
        return _typeIds.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == type).Key;
    }
}
```

The output is:

> [{"__type":"P","Name":"AbcPerson"}]

EDIT: Partial solution is to use attributes like this `[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Person), typeDiscriminator: "P")]`. But then output is like this

> [{"$type":"P","Name":"AbcPerson"}]

And I'm left with a problem of changing `$type` to `__type`.

Comment: Look at [custom naming policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy)

Comment: Also you can create DTOs with the desired property names.

Comment: What do you mean by *type names*?  Do you mean [***polymorphic** type names (i.e. type discriminators)*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#type-hierarchies)?  If so with System.Text.Json those are entirely under application control via [`JsonDerivedTypeAttribute.TypeDiscriminator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonderivedtypeattribute.typediscriminator).  Or do you mean **property names**?  Please [edit] your question and clarify with a [mcve], as suggested in [ask].

Comment: I propose to use a better title. Something like "How to Customize Property Names during Serialization using C# System.Text.Json"

Comment: @MarcoMerola - that edit might not be correct.  `JavaScriptTypeResolver` actually is for customizing type discriminator values with `JavaScriptSerializer`.  So we really need a clarification + [mcve] from the querent.

Comment: @dbc I updated the question, please, have a look at it.

Comment: Why do you need to emit a type discriminator for `Person` when it is not part of a polymorphic type hierarchy?  Are you later going to deserialize it as `object` and expect to get a `Person` back?

Comment: @dbc, I just tried to make example as small as possible. Please see the full example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascripttyperesolver?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Comment: @Yola - you may have made the example a little too small.  If your problem is about deserializing polymorphic type hierarchies without having to annotate the classes with `[JsonDerivedType]` attributes, that can be done with typeinfo modifiers, however System.Text.Json won't emit a type discriminator unless the concrete type to be serialized doesn't match the declared type, so it would be useful to have a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the type discriminator property name to `"__type"` (which is the discriminator name that was used by `JavaScriptSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer`), you need to set [`[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "__type")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpolymorphicattribute.typediscriminatorpropertyname) on every type for which you want to emit a type discriminator.  For instance, if your data model has a base type `Person` and a derived type `Adult`, you would need to modify them as follows:

```
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "__type")] // Add this here
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Person), typeDiscriminator: "P")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Adult), typeDiscriminator: "A")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "__type")] // And also here
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Adult), typeDiscriminator: "A")]
public class Adult : Person;
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f0CMrZ).

Alternatively, if you cannot modify your data models easily, you can change the [discriminator name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpolymorphismoptions.typediscriminatorpropertyname) via a [`JsonTypeInfo` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers):

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public const string MyTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "__type";
    
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> SetupMyTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName() => 
        SetupTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName(MyTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName);

    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> SetupTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName(string name) => 
        (JsonTypeInfo typeInfo) =>
    {
        if (typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions != null)
            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = name;
    };
}
```

Then use it in options e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.SetupMyTypeDiscriminatorPropertyName()),
    // Add other options as required.
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(people, options);

var people2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person []>(json, options);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0xg89Q).

See also:

- [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism).
- [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use System.Text.Json library.
If your goal is to rename the json properties based on some custom rules, you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

class CustomType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InnerCustomType InnerCustomType { get; set; }
}

class InnerCustomType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class CustomNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    Dictionary<string, string> propertyRenamingRules = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "InnerCustomType", "ICT" }
    };

    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        // Customize the conversion of class names as needed
        string alternativeName;
        if(propertyRenamingRules.TryGetValue(name, out alternativeName))
            return alternativeName;
            
        return name;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CustomType customObject = new CustomType { Id = 1, Name = "Example", InnerCustomType = new InnerCustomType { Id = 2, Name = "Example 2" }  };

        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = new CustomNamingPolicy(),
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        // Serialize the object using the custom naming policy
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(customObject, options);

        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
    }
}
```

This code prints this json:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Example",
  "ICT": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Example 2"
  }
}
```

I suggest you to have a look at this page for more documentation about the CustomNamingPolicy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Comment: There are two many classes and this solution is not easy to maintain. Also, I need for type names, not for properties.

Comment: @Yola - I suggest to better articulate your requirements in the question and also to update the title accordingly. Anyway the above example does what you need.

Comment: +, but I don't think it does. What would happen with types with the same name from different namespaces?

Comment: Wait, it doesn't work at all. You change name of a property not of a type.

Comment: @Yola - then please [edit] your question to share how you are including type names in your JSON, so it can be tested.

Comment: @dbc it is already described in my question. For now, thanks to you, I can change type names, I use things like this `[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Person), typeDiscriminator: "P")]`. But there is another problem. I'm getting `$type` instead of `__type`. And so it is not compatible with previously saved data.