# How to separate classes that extend same abstract class?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, abstract-class

My question: how do I convert a list of abstract classes back into their original classes (the classes that extend the abstract class).

I have a backend that returns a list of classes (List of UserModels) that all extends an abstract class.
something like this:

```
public abstract class UserModel
{
...
}
```

```
public abstract class ContactModel: UserModel
{
...
}
```

```
public abstract class AdminModel: UserModel
{
...
}
```

In my front-end (Angular) I have the same setup.
In C# I can simpely split those by saying `var isAdmin = someModel is AdminModel;`.

But when I get this list of users in the front-end I don't know how to convert these models from their abstract class back into the original classes.

I tried:

```
const isAdmin = Object.keys(AdminModel).every(key => user.hasOwnProperty(key));
const admin = user as AdminModel;
```

=> returned true with both models

and

```
const isAdmin = user instanceof AdminModel;
const admin = user as AdminModel;
```

=> returned false with both models

I hope this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: How are you transferring the instances from the backend to the frontend?

Comment: I have a be method: [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<List<UserModel>> GetUsers() and a method in angular: getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> { return this.getRequest(url); }

Comment: Yes, but how is the data transferred? JSON? XML? Something else?

Comment: I'm assuming it is transferred as JSON. I'm using entity framework not sure this is configurable and where this is specified.

Comment: Since it appears that everything goes to the front end as the abstract class, you'd be better off not using inheritance but maybe adding a property that specifies the type of user. I don't think JSON and polymorphism are a great match.

Comment: Add a `string TypeName` property to your abstract class.  It's implementation could simply be `string TypeName => this.GetType().Name;`.  Use it on the front end.

Comment: Thanks, added a userType property. Hoped the models could be split in the FE but this also works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON to abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class)

Comment: No, sorry this is a different problem.