# Newtonsoft.Json deserializeObject cannot get values in all generated keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

On the web side, it shows how many files and folders I add, but on the c# side, I can't get the files and folders.

```
{
    "name": "updater",
    "type": "folder",
    "path": "updater",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "tas",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "updater/tas",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "sdsadsd.txt",
                    "type": "file",
                    "path": "updater/tas/sdsadsd.txt",
                    "byte": 6
                },
                {
                    "name": "tass",
                    "type": "folder",
                    "path": "updater/tas/tass",
                    "items": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "trexs.txt",
                    "type": "file",
                    "path": "updater/tas/trexs.txt",
                    "byte": 14
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "tas2",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "updater/tas2",
            "items": []
        },
        {
            "name": "tas3",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "updater/tas3",
            "items": []
        },
        {
            "name": "tas4",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "updater/tas4",
            "items": []
        }
    ]
}
```

C# Side

```
        public class jsonFF
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string path { get; set; }
            public jsonFF[] items { get; set; }
            public long byt { get; set; }
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient updt = new WebClient();
                var updtJsonDownload = updt.DownloadString("http://localhost/update/updater.php");
                jsonFF[] json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonFF[]>(updtJsonDownload.ToString());

                foreach (var item in json)
                {
                    string sss = item.name;
                    log.Text += sss + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

what I'm trying to do is I'm trying to make a tool that will automatically take files and folders as json and check if they are on the computer on the c# side or should they be downloaded and update them.

Comment: this is not going to work. your model should have not `public object items { get; set; }` but something like `public jsonFolder[] items { get; set; }`. But you might need to add `public int byt { get; set; }` to `jsonFolder` so it can take both, array of items and represent a file

Comment: What you have is a composite pattern. And this needs a special treatment, Potencially you need to use `JObject` functionality. I found something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108058/how-to-deserialize-composite-list-with-custom-jsonconverter

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Great that you managed to solve your question! Please do add it as an answer, so that others can benefit from it as well. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

your equivalent class is wrong here. I have used [tool](https://json2csharp.com/) to get the equivalent class. `Item` class should have `byt`  property also the `Root` class should have `items`  as the list (in your case you have the object of its type)

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int? byt { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fix your jsonFolder class. Replace " object items " with  " List< jsonFolder> items " (or " jsonFolder[] items")

```
jsonFolder[] items = JsonConvert
               .DeserializeObject<jsonFolder>(updtJsonDownload.ToString()).items;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
      string sss = item.name;
      log.Text += sss + Environment.NewLine;
     }

 //or shorter
log.Text=string.Join("\n", items.Select(i =>i.name ));

//if you need file names
log.Text = string.Join("\n", items.SelectMany(i =>i.items.Select(it =>it.name ) ))); 

//if you need  pathes
string[] pathes = items.SelectMany(i =>i.items.Select(it =>it.path)).ToArray();

public class jsonFolder
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<jsonFolder> items { get; set; }
    public int? byt { get; set; }
}
```