# Why do I get a "No parameterless constructor" error when deserializing to an object?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a class with a method that serializes an object into a string and then saves it as a JSON file and another method which deserializes that file back into its original object. The serialization method functions perfectly and outputs a file with all the data in the expected JSON format.

However, on deserialization, I get the following error:

> Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a
> singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor
> annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type
> 'Octopus.Client.Model.PersistenceSettingsResource'

After researching this, I found that the most common solution is to add `[JsonConstructor] public PackagedProject() { }` to the class I'm trying to deserialize to. Not only does this result in the same error, but I'm pretty sure I've used this exact method before without having to add a constructor, though I can't say for certain my memory isn't betraying me.

Here are the relevant parts of my code, only concerned with the class definition and file serialization and deserialization:

```cs
public class PackagedProject
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public PackagedProject() { }
    public ProjectResource ProjectResource { get; set; }
    public VariableSetResource VariableSetResource { get; set; }
}

public class OctopusService
{
    public OctopusService(IConfiguration config)
    {
        var filename = "projects.json";
        SerializeProjects(packagedProject, filename);
        var deserializedProjects = DeserializedProjects(filename);
    }

    public void SerializeProjects(List<PackagedProject> projects, string filename)
    {
        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(projects, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        File.WriteAllText(filename, jsonString);
    }

    public List<PackagedProject> DeserializedProjects(string filename)
    {
        var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var fileText = File.ReadAllText(currentDir + "/" + filename);

        var deserializedProjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PackagedProject>>(fileText);
        return deserializedProjects;
    }
}
```

Additionally, the end of the error message is `Type 'Octopus.Client.Model.PersistenceSettingsResource`. I'm not sure what this means, but my best guess is that the `Octopus.Client` is the class type which is having trouble deserializing, but that doesn't make sense because I've specified that I want it to deserialize to `List<PackagedProject>`, not an `Octopus.Client` model.

- [ProjectResource model](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients/blob/master/source/Octopus.Server.Client/Model/ProjectResource.cs)
- [VariableSetResource model](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients/blob/master/source/Octopus.Server.Client/Model/VariableSetResource.cs)

Comment: Could you show code of your ProjectResource and VariableSetResource classes? And code of serialization into the file?

Comment: @Timothy 
I've added serialization method and links to models to original post

Comment: It is because your class `ProjectResource` contains field of type `PersistenceSettingsResource` [see](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients/blob/master/source/Octopus.Server.Client/Model/ProjectResource.cs#L74)

Comment: @RaminRahimzada
ProjectResource is a model imported from a package, so I don't have as much control over it as I do a class i've written myself. 

Any suggestions on how I can work around this?

Comment: @JoePringle: make a new, fresh model that is under your control. Make the two, the original model and the new model, convertible to and from. Serialize the new.

Comment: Sounds like you can fix this by [specifying a custom `[JsonConverter(...)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995865/deserializing-json-to-abstract-class) on the `PersistenceSettingsResource` property

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, my custom class `PackagedProject` contained a class imported from a package which was not compatible with System.Json's deserializer. I think Newtonsoft.json has the functionality to do this, but since i have to stick with System.Json, i had to replace the imported class with a new class that had a parameterless constructor.